# Why do I have to wait before nominating a question for deletion?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, vote-to-delete

For one thing, the whole deletion thing for questions and answers needs to be totally revamped, since it's beyond broken, but one thing at a time, IMO.

I should be able to mark any closed question as "this totally does not belong here, visible to the public", once I have enough reputation to do that (which I do on SO). There are some things that don't belong, and instead of waiting for a moderator, the community should be able to make things at least hidden from the public as soon as it's closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your frustration, but as Kyle and Tom note, the waiting period allows closing to be disputed and thus helps to prevent abuse. In situations where a post must be deleted faster, flag it: offensive and spam deletions are both automated and require no waiting period, while asking for moderator intervention can expedite the removal of inappropriate questions that don't fit into either of those categories.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree. Assuming that the post deserves it, I think that for the large majority of questions simply closing them works fine. It will drift off the front page and eventually be forgotten. Now consider the converse - a post that might be borderline, but deserves to stay open. Even though many people may want the post to remain open, they can't express this until the post is closed (there is a [request to change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close) this behavior). Instead of letting people open it back up, those same closers may immediately delete the post. Now, unless you have 10k rep and either the URL or check the moderator tools, there's no way to find it and undelete/reopen it.

In other words, the 2-day waiting period is crucial to prevent abuse of close/delete.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Kyle.  You also want a new user to see that his question was closed, and why, instead of him just wondering "What the heck happened to my question?!  I guess I'll ask it again..."

Answer (score 1):

At 20,000 reputation, the [Trusted User privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) is granted to you. The privilege allows for, amongst other things:

> - Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower
> - Voting to delete questions immediately after they are closed (even
>     if they are new)