# Why are decent questions being deleted immediately after they are closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

Recently I see a lot more questions being deleted immediately after being closed. I can understand this for negatively scored questions, but I see this with positively scored questions that I think are decent for the site as well.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562257/302677) was deleted immediately after it was closed. I thought it was a decent question, although it had some extra questions added on that pushed it into "not-constructive" for SE.

I wanted to edit it to remove the offending phrases and get it reopened, however since it was deleted by a moderator immediately after being closed, I cannot vote to reopen and it is extremely unlikely that anyone else will ever see the question.

In addition, the OP will never see that their question was closed, or why. All he/she knows is that they were getting some answers and upvotes, but then their question suddenly disappeared.

So why are decent questions being deleted immediately after being closed? Is this some new policy I haven't heard of since I've only noticed it recently?

Comment: *"[I] see many new WPF users who have this kind of question"* If that's true, then wouldn't it be closed as a duplicate?  Can you find one of the other, older questions on this topic to answer?  Or are is every single question on this topic (back to the beginning of time) deleted?

Comment: @Servy There might be duplicates out there, but typically I see this kind of question in comments or as part of the text in a different question. Its actually one I asked myself when I first started learning MVVM (although I didn't post a question on SO).

Comment: Slightly beside the point: But the whole immediate deletion thing needs to be reconsidered. Too often I see 20ks and moderators delete a question immediately after closing. The OP has no chance to learn why X question was unsuitable. Perhaps there should be a "timed deletion" vote that allows you to automatically cast a delete vote X days later without needing to come back.

Comment: @Mysticial An alternate implementation could be just that deleted posts are visible to <10k users if they are less than X [units] old.

Comment: @Servy That was probably the intended purpose. But I get the feeling that people cast immediate delete votes because they know they will not come back later.

Comment: @Mysticial I think you're right, and I like your solution of being able to cast timed delete votes :) However I don't think the delete vote should get processed (if a moderator delete) if an edit gets made to the question, or if it has reopen votes. If someone edits the question to make it valid, and there are some re-open votes on it, we don't want a single moderator vote to be suddenly deleting the question.

Comment: @Mysticial - There was a recent discussion about this in [How long should I wait before deleting a closed question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138686/how-long-should-i-wait-before-deleting-a-closed-question). I think the answers there cover this topic well.

Comment: @BradLarson Note that the meta question is in regards to users, not moderators.  We're tasked with different responsibilities.

Comment: @BradLarson So I guess the problem we need to solve is in my second comment: *People cast immediate delete votes because they know they won't come back.* So either a list of 2-day closed questions or a time-delete feature needs to be implemented.

Comment: BTW, "decent" is a subjective term, it's not an absolute gauge of the quality of the question.

Comment: Also, upvotes != quality, just popularity.

Comment: I'm reopening this post-edits, but I'm pretty sure this is now a duplicate. Looking...

Comment: Good luck on timed reminders on stuff here ... we've been asking for that sort of functionality for a while

Comment: Can you show examples where you don't have skin in the game?  In this example question and the one you reference in [Nicol's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140463/140951) you have answers on both.  Would you show examples where you believe this to be the case where you have *not* participated?

Comment: @casperOne I will see if I can find some other examples for you, but its hard to search deleted questions. I only have references to these two since they're linked in my profile

Comment: @Rachel The examples aren't as much for me as much as it is for those that might look at the answers and possibly wonder about other motives.  It never hurts to provide examples where one is completely dissociated from the results.

Comment: @casperOne You realize this is almost impossible with the tools available, right? The only way find deleted questions is the 10k tools, which only shows the last 50 deleted posts. This means I can only view the last hour or so of deletions, and 90%+ are deleted answers, not deleted Qs. The only other deleted questions I can find are the ones that contain a link in my profile. I have seen other positively scored questions that were immediately deleted though, typically while I'm viewing the question or writing an answer when they get deleted. I just haven't bothered to question it until now.

Comment: @Rachel Long story short though, there's going to be stuff that comes off as obvious crap to some moderators (myself included) so we're going to just delete it.  In those cases, a close reason is preferred so that there's *some* indication as to why.  Sometimes, we get it right, sometimes, we get it wrong.  When we get it wrong, it gets brought here, the community decides, and the system works.  That said, the volume of posts on SO necessitates action like this in order to maintain some sense of quality in the face of ever-increasing amounts of crap.

Comment: @casperOne I agree there is a lot of crap that should be deleted immediately, however if you close something with a positive score and positively scored answers, please leave a comment as to why it's closed and don't delete it immediately to give users a chance to edit and re-open the question if they can. In regards to the 2nd question I linked, I still got upvotes as recent as the day you deleted it, so it was obviously helping some people.

Comment: @Rachel Again, votes != quality or usefullness, just popularity.  It's not definitive that votes mean that they're useful to *someone*.  Also, the question you linked to and tried to save (you did a number of edits that I don't necessarily agree with) still don't make the question a good fit, IMO.  I can't say that this is going to change.  When something is abysmal, it's got to go.   As it was, it was abysmal.  The answers weren't saving it.  You need an Eric Lippert type answer to save questions like that.

Comment: @casperOne Questions don't need to be perfect. They just need to be valid. An additional reason to not delete positively scored questions immediately is because it gives the OP a chance to see why they were closed. I'm sure users can easily figure out why negatively scored questions get deleted (and are probably even happy when they are), but when positively scored questions get deleted, I'm sure they have questions about why and what was wrong with it.

Comment: @Rachel That's a problem with the system, not a people problem.  I personally don't agree that people who have questions deleted shouldn't be able to find them.  Those people always have meta as well to come and ask why or where it went.  Again, there are multiple systems in place to handle the times when this approach isn't the right one and they haven't failed yet, *the system works*.

Comment: I agree with you that people should be able to view their own deleted questions, although only a fraction of people who use SO actually know of and use meta. It took me months to notice the [meta] link up top, and the first time I visited here, I thought it was a Q&A site for the admins, and didn't come back until months later when SE got rid of the `/recent` page

Comment: @Rachel While I don't disagree that there's a lack of communication *about* the system, that is a *separate problem unrelated to this*.  As to whether or not people will learn how to use meta, well, you've learned to use meta just fine.  I don't doubt that other's will have that hurdle either.

Answer (score 8):

Technology, like a time limit, is not going to solve this problem. This is a people-problem, and it can only be solved by people.

Personally, I think casperOne is getting a little trigger-happy as a mod. Not only did he immediately delete the original question for no adequately explained reason (closing it is fine, insta-deleting it is *not*), he also closed *this question* as "Too Localized", even though talking about moderator and community actions on questions *is exactly what Meta sites are for*. This is rather unacceptable and skirts dangerously close to a mod trying to cover their own tracks when they did something wrong.

At the very least, a moderator should almost never close a meta question that is discussing their own actions. If the question is close-worthy, another moderator can do it.

Comment: Maybe it should be made that a moderator can't delete a question with their mod powers that they also closed with their mod powers.

Comment: You may be right that this is only the actions of one moderator. I know I recently lost a bunch of rep from [another question that was closed and deleted immediately](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3533212/302677), so I looked it up just now and it was casperOne again. I can't remember who closed/deleted the other questions I noticed recently though. Its hard to find them if they're not linked in my profile somewhere.

Comment: Upvote for "this is a people problem", not sure that the criticism against casp is absolutely on-target, I think there's just a lot more volume of crap than people realize ... In response to "a mod should never close a meta question discussing their behavior", I agree in 90% of cases, I suppose.

Comment: You might recall that the [original revision of this question before it was closed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/140435/2) was a *highly* localized question, even though it was under the guise of a broader question.  That said, the situation around *that revision* question [was resolved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140442/140951) and it was closed as TL because it was question-specific.  Once the question was edited to *truly* be more general and reopened, I deleted my answer (as it was question-specific and the question was broad).

Comment: As for the "people" (me), well, there's a lot of crap on the site.  Call it whatever you want, but honestly, you don't really know the definition of trigger-happy given you have no real stats about how many things I or other mods process on a daily basis, as well as what our respective error rates are. Needless to say from the error metrics that *are tracked*, I can say that my error rate is somewhere around 2% (and that's given *tens of thousands* (30K+ all-time, 300+ *today*) of flags processed). If that's your definition of trigger happy, then I'd dare say you're being overzealous, at best.

Comment: Also, it should be noted, the system works.  The original revision of this question was about the closure and deletion of a specific question, and that question was undeleted (by me) and reopened (by the community).  Even here, after the question was edited (after my informing @Rachel as to why the question was too localized in the comments of my answer) it was reopened.  Again, the system works.  So what's your point?  It's not a people problem either.  It would be a people problem if the system *didn't* work, so I'm not too sure what your answer is adding here.

Comment: @casperOne: I'm rather unclear about your definition of "work." The OP of the linked question did *not* repair the question; Rachel did. I have no idea how she got the link to that question, but in most cases, when a question is deleted, it's *gone*. If nobody has a link, it's not getting fixed. Ever. So I disagree that this is "working". Or more to the point, I don't trust a system that appears to work when the evidence of it working is based around luck.

Comment: @casperOne: "you don't really know the definition of trigger-happy given you have no real stats about how many things I or other mods process on a daily basis" No, but this is not the first time I've seen you called out for quickly deleting something. That may be anecdotal evidence, but it's not like SE makes it easy to track down which mods are more "trigger-happy" than others. So unless SE devises a simple means to track which moderators close&delete questions more frequently than others, we make due with the information we have.

Comment: @NicolBolas "So unless SE devises a simple means to track which moderators close&delete questions more frequently than others, we make due with the information we have." - Make a feature request for it.  Until then, frankly, you should not make overreaching statements about things you have little evidence to base them on.  "Making due" is not enough.  My numbers come from the horse's mouth (I asked SE).

Comment: As for the definition of work, @Rachel had an answer on the question and is a 10K user, so it shows up on her profile (did you even look at the question, she edited it and has the top-voted answer on it)?

Comment: @casperOne: "did you even look at the question" I looked at the question; I didn't look at the answers, as they're more or less irrelevant. But that makes my point for me. If Rachel was *not* a 10K user, there would have been *nothing* that could have been done. Whereas if you had just closed the question, she would have been able to correct it and get it reopened without this MSO thread and without being a 10K user. So again, the system only works by a matter of luck. I don't trust a system that works based on good fortune.

Comment: @casperOne: " My numbers come from the horse's mouth" The other problem with this is that there's no way to tell what you *real* error ratio is. You say it's 2%, meaning (as I understand it) that 2% of questions you delete are undeleted eventually. Well, what of the other 98% that might have been *fixable* that weren't undeleted because no 10K user happened to be involved? No statistics can tell us about that.

Comment: It's obvious you have an issue with my moderation style.  I would recommend being more direct about it and separate it out from this post and put it in another meta post.  As it stands now, you really don't answer @Rachel question for the general case, you are simply ranting about me.