# More difficult to close question as duplicate

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aggressively closing duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8578/aggressively-closing-duplicate-questions)

I think the vote to close could be bit better.

I know people (me included) can be too lazy to ask questions that should not have been asked because they are duplicate or something else.

At the same time I think people can be too lazy when closing the questions. I don't think this scenario is uncommon. One user comes along and finds a question that he thinks should be closed. The next user sees the question and sees that someone has voted to close, so he does the same thing without thinking too much about it, and soon the question is closed.

Perhaps [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22503/feature-request-new-system-for-agreeing-and-discussing-on-whether-to-close-quest) about it before a question should be closed is too much, but I believe that it should be more difficult to close a question that already have multiple answers and views.

Perhaps giving the user you asked the question a second change to be edit the question.

At a minimum I think you should be required to leave a comment when closing a question, perhaps not all 5 users, perhaps only the first 2.

Comment: this is my comment: asfhsdifhsdifhsidfhsdifhsdifhdsifd

Comment: This is a dupe. Because I'm too lazy I just close as too localized.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8578

Comment: @Dow: Why do you do that?

Comment: capped and bored @john

Answer (score 4):

> Perhaps giving the user you asked the question a second change to be edit the question.

They already have that. The question can be editing even after it is closed, and could in fact be edited to the point where it should be re-opened.

> At a minimum I think you should be required to leave a comment when closing a question, perhaps not all 5 users, perhaps only the first 2.

There's a reason why every time this comes up it gets shot down. That reason is Downvoter's comment on your question. :)

If anything, closing duplicates *isn't easy enough.* It takes 5 people, many of whom may not notice the four close votes on something that is blatantly a dupe. Additionally, we only get 12 close votes per day across all the closure reasons. This conspires to make us selective about what we close.

My advice to you is that if you feel your question was unfairly closed (for whatever reason), edit it to point out why it was unfairly closed. That'll bump it and get you some exposure for getting it reopened.

Comment: I'm upvoting this even though user0x36E0 is chasing me for the next 10k spot. That's how much I agree with it.