# Possibility to remove an own vote

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

It would be nice to be able to undo an own close-vote while the voting is still running, for example when I see that the author just has improved on the question.

Or maybe, with [my other proposal for making keep-open votes while close-vote is running](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65736/vote-against-a-running-close-vote) that such a reopen-vote will automatically undo my previos close-vote.