# more close-votes should be needed to close

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I think it would be better if more close-votes would be needed to close a question; at least the way it is right now.

The problem is that a once-closed question is very unlikely to be reopened because not much people will see it anymore and the other people will not check back. If the author knows how to improve the question, it doesn't make sense anymore to edit the question because not much people will see that anymore. The current only real solution is to just repost the question; however, that is not a really nice solution.

I made a few other proposals which maybe would make this request obsolete to need more close-votes:

- [vote against a running close-vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65736/vote-against-a-running-close-vote)
- [possibility to remove an own vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65738/possibility-to-remove-an-own-vote)

However, without them, I really think more close-votes should be needed. If the question is really bad, it would also not need much time to get 10 close votes or so together.

Answer (score 4):

When you edit a question it gets bumped back to the top of the Active tab, so more people *should* see it.  Questions get reopened all the time, so this system seems to be working.

Comment: I actually have not seen much questions being reopened. The only chance is that it had gain much attraction already before, otherwise people will just ignore it.

Comment: @Albert: How do you know? A reopened question looks just like a question that wasn't ever closed.

Comment: @Piskvor: I mean I have not seen any question in a closed state and then again at a reopened state later on (except for some rare cases of own questions). Also, from comments on the question, I think you can see if a question was first closed and then reopened.

Comment: @Piskvor and Albert: one can see in the revision history, but then indeed needs to bump into it. Like http://stackoverflow.com/posts/841481/revisions or http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1621480/revisions