# Can locking a post discourage new answers? (And a solution)

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

*A bit of background:*

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature) was locked to stop the cycle of close, reopen, close, reopen...
 
*(The question is irrelevant. It's just an example)*

But, apparently, you *can* still add answers to this question. **I didn't even know that was possible.** I thought the entire *thread* was locked down. I'm assuming a lot of people would make the same mistake.

Might I suggest that *most* people don't know what it means (or don't care) that a question has been locked. It could be confusing to users and potentially harmful to the question.

#### A Solution

The solution would be to remove the general notice and just show a descriptive popup if someone tries to click the link of a "locked function." In this case, clicking on the `close` link pops up:

> **A moderator has disabled closing for this question.** `[click to dismiss]`"

It avoids the confusion and avoids "branding" the question in a negative light (everything looks "normal" to most users).

*'Just a random thought about usability and the user experience.*

Comment: Lock = you can only perform operations on this specific locked instance and not kill it nor spawn any new ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I think that's a bit misleading too.

What about if instead of the currently:

> *This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on.*

The system shows:

> *This post has been locked;  you can still add answers*

Comment: You can still mark it as a "favorite" too; should then be, *"This post has been locked; you can still add answers and/or mark it as a 'favorite'. Also, you can edit and/or vote on existing answers. Comments on existing answers work too. Really, most stuff still works, except for the bits that operate directly on the question itself; you should probably just do what you want, and rely on a notification like this one to let you know if what you're trying to do is disallowed."*

Comment: @Shog9 - That's why I thought it made more sense to pop up a notification ***if*** a user attempted a "locked" operation... rather than labeling the post with terminology *most* people wont understand (or even care): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34815/give-diamond-moderators-the-ability-to-partially-lock-a-post/34831#34831

Answer (score 2):

**Locked** means no votes, edits, or comments may be added to a post. By "post" we mean question or answer.

**Closed** means no more answers may be added to a question.

They are totally different and independent concepts, at least from the SO perspective.

Comment: Is there a potential problem with users adding answers in lieu of comments?

Comment: @Roger: that's *always* a potential problem. Even on questions that haven't been locked.

Comment: I just assumed "locked by..." meant that the entire Q/A thread was frozen in time, forever. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

If a popular question is locked to prevent closing or deletion, then it's probably a bit late to worry about discouraging answers. I'd love to know how many of the 29K viewers of that question you link to actually read the 100+ existing answers before posting their own...

I don't think anything else needs to be done. If the big "Your Answer" box at the bottom isn't a clue that answers are still accepted, it's probably just as well.