# Typo in error message when commenting on an un-commentable post

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, spelling, error-message

When trying to submit a comment on a deleted answer, the message

> Cannot add comments to this post; it maybe locked, deleted, or frozen

pops up, but there's a typo.

Fix: `s/maybe/may be/g`

I saw this on Linguistics, but presumably it occurs everywhere.

Comment: What is frozen? Wouldn't that be the same thing as locked? I've never heard that term used here before. o.o

Comment: @animuson I searched on Meta and found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36977/147650).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Typo was introduced as part of exposing comment creation in API V2.1, lots of code got moved around to accommodate it.