# Make it possible to lock an answer against editing but not against comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, locked

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add the ability to lock a question against edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62554/add-the-ability-to-lock-a-question-against-edits)

I've noticed that [the `<center>` cannot hold it is too late](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) answer is locked. I don't have a problem with not being able to edit the answer (which is why it was locked), but I'd like to be able to add another comment.

Comment: I was recently talking to [Will](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will) about a similar case; locking flexibility in general would be nice (locking some combination of voting, editing, and commenting, not just all or none)