# I’m losing 500+ reputation since great rep recalc

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, reputation-recalc

To be honest, I haven’t been very active on Stack Overflow in the last few weeks and I’ve only taken up the slack in the last few *days*. I’m therefore astonished to see (via the `/reputation` link) that my reputation will go down by 578 points (from currently 64,668 to 64,090) with the next reputation recalc.

Since I haven’t done much since the [*last* recalc](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/) (that I’m aware of), and the rules for reputation haven’t changed (or have they?) this doesn’t seem right.

I haven’t noticed any “unusual” votes that would be undone, haven’t deleted any high-scoring answers, and in any case **more than 500 rep** would seem excessive even then.

What other reasons for losing that much rep are there?

(I want to stress again that this is from *after* the great rep recalc, so the changing reputation gain for question upvotes has already been applied. What I’m seeing here is unrelated.)

Comment: By the way, I didn’t invent the `oh-noes` tag but it seemed appropriate here.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/reputation tell you the reputation you _will_ lose in the future? How? Where?

Comment: @Daniel Daranas: Well, it tells you the “real” reputation while the reputation shown on top of the SOFU pages show only an approximation that doesn’t take into account rep lost via deleted questions, loss from undone “suspicious” votes and rep gain from capped reputation that cancels out downvotes from the same day.

Comment: Konrad, I've posted undeletion request here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50601/can-we-undelete-and-or-merge-following-questions - I hope you get most reps back.

Comment: I think i lost more than that.

Comment: Count yourself lucky, I lost 2000 - dropped me back below 10k too

Comment: @Blorgbeard: That’s tough. :-( But just to get this out of the way: in the “great” rep recalc, I also lost substantially more rep. But given that the *rules* for accruing rep had been changed, that was to be expected.

Comment: @Juan but I *loved* that `oh-noes` tag. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen some of the questions you've answered, listed on the delete candidate page under 10k tools, and almost all the question on that list got deleted, so probably thats the reason why you see the drop on /reputation

Comment: Huh. I didn’t know that I posted in many questions that were going to be deleted (and I can’t see any such questions now) but now that I look at the list, there are entirely too many deletions for my taste.

Comment: @Konrad It is also mostly the same people deleting.

Comment: @Konrad, Yeah, we can't know which answer is going to be deleted, but most of them are off topic and poor written questions. If you found valid questions, you could post here in meta, to get undelete it back by some moderators.

Comment: @Konrad, without being able to see the questions, I guess this then relates to [Why are we deleting instead of merging?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50069/why-are-we-deleting-instead-of-merging/50106#50106)

Comment: @S.Mark Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148358/can-i-use-c-to-create-a-windows-gui-application-it-seems-like-its-only-good) question? Perfectly reasonable question. Or [this  one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521341/whats-the-difference-between-nsstring-stringvalue-vs-nsstring-stringvalue-cl). Sure it had been asked before but it didn't need to be deleted. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055608/is-there-a-stackoverflow-iphone-app-closed) should have been moved to meta. The list goes on. (All those were deleted in the past 24 hours)

Comment: Yeah @Yacoby, I agree that those posts should not be deleted. but I sometimes involved deletion of those questions, I couldn't say too loudly.

Comment: Merged question get deleted *eventually*, just after the mod moves the answers.

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, that’s kind of related. Thanks for pointing it out.