# Can we undelete and/or merge following questions?

Tags: discussion, support, undelete

According to [Konrad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50596/im-losing-500-reputation-since-great-rep-recalc)'s post on meta, And I know I seen some of his post with high votes deleted (I admit that I also involved), so I searched some of my saved data back in my pc. Here is I found so far.

- **+13** - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909674/why-is-vb-so-popular
- **+13** - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354494/is-division-by-2-faster-than-multiplication-by-2-closed
- **+10** - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110870/how-do-i-break-lines-in-python
- **+8** - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662389/can-every-recursive-function-be-converted-to-a-non-recursive-form
- **+1**  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362228/should-the-pointer-symbol-go-on-the-type-name-or-the-variable-name-in-c

When I see it again now, I feels that all of those posts are valid, So can we undeleted those back, and/or merge it, (lock if needed?), if possible?

I feel guilty, since I involved deletion of some of those questions. Some of those answers really really good, If I look again now.

Or

Do you think those are appropriate to delete? (feels free to downvote to show disaggrement)

Comment: Also see [why-are-we-deleting-instead-of-merging?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50069/why-are-we-deleting-instead-of-merging)

Comment: [Another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748299) that I don't think should have been deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think deleting posts should be done as a last resort or for really bad posts. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865891/fdff-fad-fad-gfda-gfadg-closed) was right to be deleted it doesn't add anything and is just spam. There are of course a lot of other examples.

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148358/can-i-use-c-to-create-a-windows-gui-application-it-seems-like-its-only-good) should (IMHO) have been left undeleted or merged with one of the duplicates. It wasn't a great question and the answers weren't anything amazing, but I remember googling for a similar sort of thing 6 years ago. Even if it is a duplicate, the question is asked differently to the duplicates and so will probably come up for a different google search terms. If this is to become a better resource for programmers, duplicates should be left open for google to index.

One thing I have noticed is there is no FAQ entry that I could find that explains *when* questions should be deleted.

Comment: +1 for "needs a FAQ entry explaining delete powers" - Also see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message)

Answer (score 2):

You can flag deleted questions for moderator attention, if you believe they should be merged.

Comment: I personally shouldn't decide, so I am posting here :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks for finding these links – awesome.

I’ve had a look at the now and some of these threads are actually incredibly good, even the subjective/argumentative question on the virtues of VB.

The bottom line is that this has made me aware once again of the existence of the “tools” tab and I vow to use it more frequently from now on, to take active part in the deletion (and hopefully more common undeletion) of questions.

(So something good has come out of my rep loss.)

**EDIT** Three of these questions (plus one mentioned in the comments) have now been merged and one (the last) is probably not a very big loss. I’d count that as a big success.

Comment: 500 out of 64,000 is massive?

Comment: @The Cat: All right – tiny. I meant it in relation to adjustments done in a rep recalc. I don’t have statistics but 500 seems quite a lot for a mere *recalc*.

Comment: In the recalc a few months ago, some users lost 30-50% of their rep.  (Others gained, too.)  Less than 1% doesn't seem like much to me. *\*shrug\**

Comment: @The Cat: Right, I didn’t know that. True, compared to that 500 *is* tiny.