# Question was *HARD* deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110870/how-do-i-break-lines-in-python) which was referenced [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates) just seems **not to exist** at all.

Even to 10K users!

What happened to it?

I thought questions do **not** really get deleted, but just put in a state where >10K users can see them.

Is this something new?

Comment: Looks like someone really didn't want that duplicate to stick around...

Comment: Looks like a feature reqeust in the making: Make the dead part(s) of a merged question point to the new.

Comment: @AndersUP I think I should make a new question though for it...

Comment: @AndersUP [Follow up question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188593/155556)

Comment: Related (hard deleted by Atwood himself): [the boat programming question](https://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/). It was also referenced at 1 h 02 min 43 secs in [episode 50 of the Stack Overflow podcast](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-28), classic series (2009-04-21).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A merge operation was requested for that question in May 2010 (see [Can we undelete and/or merge following questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50601/164403)).

At the time, merging would hard-delete the merge source, since it was considered that all the information deemed useful would become available in the merge target question.

A month later, this behavior [was removed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/10/improved-question-merging/) and merge stubs are now left behind on question merging, but this means nothing for previous merges.

Comment: Well that is a **bug** then. Merging should __not__ do a hard delete! That makes very little sense...

Comment: Not sure how a merge works behind the scenes, but perhaps it doesn't intentionally delete it - just changes how things link together?

Comment: "Merging may very well hard-delete the original" If that was the case before then it no longer is. But then again I was only a mod starting in late 2011, so I'm not sure if things were different before I got on board.

Comment: @Frederic [Follow up question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188593/155556)

Comment: Merges _and_ migrations used to hard delete the origin, which they no longer do but did for a short time. I can't be _positive_ that's what happened here as there's well .. nothing to see any longer, but I'm 99.9999999% sure that's what it was. They were never hard deleted 'in theory' as they technically just 'moved' but well we saw how that went, which is why it was fixed.