# A question that was merged should not get *HARD* deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-questions, merged-questions

As a follow up to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188590/155556) which was answered correctly --

Merged questions should get automatically forwarded to the new version of the question and I should not land on a 404 page like I do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110870/how-do-i-break-lines-in-python)

It ***should*** follow the same rules as when we move a question to a different Stack Exchange site -- Have the option of seeing the orginal Question when you have the `noredirect` option, or it should just forward to the new question.

---

Explanation:

It is **not** a hard delete in the fact that the post is deleted from the SE database -- as you can see the title of the Question in you're browser's title bar -- but it is deleted in a way that there was no real indication of how or why the question was deleted (or even if the post *was* in fact a question) and no >10K users can see the Original Question.

---

Interesting --

I now get "Page Not Found - Stack Overflow" in the title bar. I *was* getting the post's title before, unless I was hallucinating (which is possible, but all I drank today was water).

---

If the above was not enough, here is what I think happens currently and what *should* happen in the future:

*What happens currently* (in steps):

1. Click on a link to a **merged** Stack Exchange Question
2. Reach a page not found (aka 404) page
3. Wonder what just happened...
4. Go back to see if you read the link correctly
5. Click on it again
6. Reach the same 404 page
7. Ask on meta.so why this is happening
8. Drink some water while waiting for an explanation (and *maybe* do some **actual** work)

What *should* happen (in steps):

1. Click on a link to a **merged** Stack Exchange Question
2. The page should get ***forwarded*** to the post that it got merged into
3. There should be some indication on the page **telling you** what happened so you do not think that you clicked on the wrong thing accidentally.

---

Since @RobertHarvey wants me to tell you [why children will starve in Ethiopia if this does not happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188593/a-question-that-was-merged-should-not-get-hard-deleted?noredirect=1#comment581071_188593):

**They won't**, or it just **will not affect them**.

But people who have links to these questions and did not realize that they were being merged and have **over** 10K rep on the site can get confused and not now what happened to these questions and will assume them to be deleted... but with the caveat that they cannot see them for some reason -- There should be **some indication** that a merge happened in these cases.

Comment: You can see the question title in the title bar? I only get "Page Not Found - Stack Overflow".

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi interesting... Now **I get** "Page not found" also.

Comment: *Someone is busy covering their tracks.* `</paranoia>`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi hehe Updated ^_^

Comment: This would be a better post if you explained *why* the merged post should not be hard-deleted.  A merge copies all of the information from the source post to the target one and removes most of that information from the source post (leaving a stub), so why would you need the stub to hang around forever, even as a soft-delete, if most of the original information is preserved?

Comment: @RobertHarvey well the link should **forward** to the new post and not just go to a "Page Not Found page". That is kind of confusing. And then when it does forward, it should explain **why**.

Comment: AFAIK it *does* do that for a certain period of time.  I don't know what that period is exactly, but it's somewhere around six to eight weeks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I updated my OP

Comment: You still haven't explained why this is a problem, although you are dancing around it.  Tell us why children will starve in Ethiopia if this does not happen.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I did if you look at my steps for What happens currently.

Comment: All you're describing there is your own confusion.  So you're saying that instead of the link 404'ing, it should say "This post was removed for reasons of moderation?"  After sixty days you would think the OP would have figured it out by then.

Comment: @Robert - migrated questions auto-forward, right?  I would think merged questions ought to behave the same.  I would think this would be rather obvious and not in need of explanation.

Comment: @AdamRackis I thought so too...

Comment: @RobertHarvey updated again...

Comment: Note that migrated questions are not guaranteed to keep their stubs forever, either.

Comment: But...this [already happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187287/how-should-we-deal-with-ops-that-edit-in-answer-to-question). It just presumably can't happen for legacy merges, because they were more destructive.

Comment: @TimStone it doesn't _really_ already happen (it forwards you nowhere). Also how do we know that it won't _automatically_ get deleted after X amount of time?

Comment: It absolutely does redirect you, if you aren't logged in (or it may be reputation-based, I'm not sure). I imagine it does get automatically deleted at some point, but since the answers are preserved on the target question I'm not sure how large of an issue that is.

Comment: @TimStone if the link is posted to some link sharing site and the post **is** deleted eventually, the link becomes useless...

Comment: That's a general issue with deleting questions, and isn't specific to merging.

Comment: @TimStone When a question is deleted >10K users **can see the question** and the others get a reason for why it was dleeted. In this case there is **nothing**

Comment: ...Yes, because those were legacy merges. If the stub I linked is deleted automatically, I guarantee it will be accessible to 10k users.

Comment: @Tim - it sounds like you know what is going on here - can you post an answer and put this to bed?

Comment: @AdamRackis Well, I can't absolutely confirm the current behaviour, so I'm a bit reluctant to state that as fact. But I don't see why it would be any different than what I said now that the merging process has been improved.

Comment: @Shog9 -- This is **not** completed and **not** a duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

I AGREE WHOLEHEARTEDLY!

That's why I was so happy when this was fixed. [**Three years ago**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/).

You can find the answers to that particular question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python).

Comment: Why is there the impression that this is borken?  Is the cited link more than three years old?

Comment: Yes, it is @Robert. Had to use archive.org to find out where the answers went.

Comment: Interestingly, the 404 page lists your link as the first suggestion for similar questions. :)

Comment: Sounds like it probably *was* a duplicate then... ;-P

Comment: @Shog9 this is not a duplicate **at all** There is no indication that you were forwarded at all.. Quite confusing.

Comment: Yes, @amana, the system was really, really broken... Until it was fixed... Three years ago. There are some - though thankfully relatively few - remnants of this. It isn't really possible to do anything about then, since they *were* **hard deleted**.

Comment: @Shog9 ok. but That "duplicate" had nothing to do with my feature request. My feature request is that there should be some indication that a merge happened and why you were forwarded to where you were sent to.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Uh, and Shog is saying that that already happens, and it's been that way for the last three years, and we can't do anything about the stubs that were hard deleted more than three years ago.

Comment: @RobertHarvey there is **no indication** that you were forwarded at all...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Not on the post you linked.  It was hard-deleted before the problem was fixed.  Why are you beating a dead horse?

Comment: @RobertHarvey See the posy Shog9 used in his answer. No indication of merge...

Comment: @aman would you like them to try to manually figure out what old posts were merged and update the database so that it displays the appropriate notice for these old questions, or what? What are you suggesting be done?