# When should a closed question be flagged for deletion?

Tags: discussion, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I vote to delete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete)

When is it appropriate to flag closed questions for deletion?

Here are 4 closed "give me the code" questions. (contains text "give me the code")

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959218/can-any-one-give-me-the-code-for-sample-registartion-page-with-validations-in-and
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710513/how-to-initialize-servlet
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509323/delta-compression
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898032/i-want-code-for-how-to-deletecookies-in-htmlunitdriver-without-opening-the-browse

I believe these would be OK to flag, but I'm not sure what the community wants in this regard.

If it's closed, but still so poor that it is cluttering up the site, should it be flagged?

Does it change if there are answers?

Does it change if it's a couple years old?

What is a proper guideline to follow in regards to flagging closed questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only flag for deletion those questions that are completely hopeless and useless.  If it's like that and I can't edit it into shape, then it is probably a good candidate for deletion.

A big factor is if it has any good answers.

1. Decent answer, no flag.
2. ok answers, no flag.
3. kill it quickly before it spreads
4. Decent answer, no flag.

NOTE:  I'm talking about flagging for deletion, they may still be good to flag for merging.

Comment: I always have the option of editing a "give me the code" to a "how do I accomplish this goal...", but there is approximately 0% chance that the author provides any useful feedback to answers. That said, I agree with you on principle, and should probably stop flagging these.

Comment: yeh, you're right about a those kind of users not really participating in their question.