# When should a question be deleted?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I vote to delete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete)

I've been getting a lot of privileges lately, and I don't really know how some of them should be used.

For example, voting to close a question is clear enough, but when should a question be marked for deletion?

I don't mean the obvious spam that may arise (not that I've seen any yet, myself), but actual questions of low quality. How bad does a question have to be for it to be deletable?

Comment: I'd ask myself this: Would this be a question that I would like to show off to other people to show how cool the site is?  If not and it's closed long enough with a negative score, delete.

Comment: Delete early, delete often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FAQ helps you a bit under the section *"[Why are some questions or answers removed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion)"* stating that:

> *Questions that are [extremely off topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.*
>
> *Over time, closed questions that are not useful as signpoints to other questions may also be removed, as well as questions which have no significant activity over a very long period after being asked. For additional guidance, see [How to Ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask).*

Every site has this section, I'm taking the MSO FAQ as an example.

So, apart from duplicates — which are usually those *signpoints*<sup>**1**</sup> the quote above refers to — other questions are deleted after a certain amount of time.

In summary, the most common types are:

- Spam (deleted on sight);
- Extremely off-topic questions (closed/deleted/migrated soon after posting);
- Closed questions that don't serve any real purpose for the site (after some more time).

---

<sup>**1**: Duplicates are useful even when closed because if a new user finds the duplicate, instead of the original, this will prevent another "dupe's dupe", pointing that same user to the original question.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Generally questions that are deleted are those questions that are not useful for the site where they are asked, such as off-topic, not constructive, not real, and too localized questions.

Duplicated questions are generally not deleted because they can help who is searching the duplicated question. Clearly, if a user submits the exact same question twice, the newer question is closed, and deleted (or directly deleted from a moderator).