# When should I delete an answer?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

In [When should I vote to delete a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete), we only cover questions.

When should 20k users vote to delete answers?

Should this be discussed on a site-by-site basis? Why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An answer that is not an answer should be deleted (should be a comment, doesn't answer the question etc...).

Answers that *are* answers but are factually wrong or are actively *bad* (say promote SQL Injection) should get downvoted, but not deleted.

Comment: Why *not* vote to delete a -10 answer that is factually wrong and actively bad? To serve as an example?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Because they still have a right to provide the answer, and seeing an approach widely considered wrong is still useful information, as opposed to trying to stick your head in the sand.

Comment: Because although the answer is bad, and wrong. It is an answer.

Comment: I gotta say I disagree, and I regularly vote to delete answers with harmful information. Seeing the negative score is OK to prevent people from using it, but if the answer itself isn't valuable I see no reason to keep it around, especially when the user is inactive and not likely to revise it or delete it themselves.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - I think that seeing what the community believes is a bad answer is valuable. And if someone chooses to use such an answer, they at least know others think it is a bad idea.

Comment: What about cases of community fail? E.g. if an *objectively* harmful or wrong answer is up voted?

Comment: @Sklivvz - Grasping at straws? Community fail would also mean that the answer wouldn't get deleted.

Comment: Right, I forgot one needs -ve score... point taken