# Review of Low Quality answers offers unsatisfactory choices of actions

Tags: discussion, bug, review, low-quality-posts

According to [When should I delete an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163730/148099), answers that are earnest attempts at an explanation, but that are technically incorrect, should be downvoted but not deleted.

However, the Low Quality review queue does not offer an easy way to do the right thing:

[image: Screenshot: Review of low quality answer]

- **"Looks OK"** is inappropriate: "nothing is wrong" doesn't apply to a wrong answer.
- **"Edit"** is inappropriate: Any edit that corrects the answer would also radically alter the meaning of the post.
- **"Recommend Deletion"** is inappropriate since it is an earnest but misguided attempt at an answer.
- **"Skip"** is, unfortunately, the only way to clear this item from the queue.  However, skipping items isn't letting the reviewer be helpful.

Therefore, the Low Quality review queue needs to offer better choices of actions.

Comment: Voting is indication, not **resolving**!

Comment: **Skip** in case of any doubts! You might go to that question directly (using open in another tab or window if you like), and dowvote as you like.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is in fact what I did. But the fact remains that the UI is confounding, frustrating, and arguably unreasonable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In light of your feedback, I have modified the feature request into a bug report and proposed an alternate solution.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest possible improvement would be to rename the "Looks OK" button to "Keep".  Unlike "Looks OK", which implies that the reviewer *approves* of the answer, "Keep" merely states that the reviewer doesn't think that it should be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The review has the options that are basically 'keep it' or 'delete it'.

Its goal is "Identify, then improve or delete low-quality posts"  Thus, there are three options:

- Looks OK if it isn't a low quality post
- Edit if the post can be improved and you are willing to make such improvements to fix *all* the problems.
- Recommend deleting it (or casting a delete vote if you are 20k).

The guidelines beyond that are fuzzy.  Each site has its own threshold for what low quality is.  Some are rather "delete it" others are "it should be preserved for all time."  This fits with the community voting and reviewing to have the site be what they want it to become when they come looking.

If that is the quality of the answer that you are ok with on the site, then hit 'looks ok'.  If it is something that can be improved, edit it.  If it isn't what you want on the site, then delete it.

The quality of the site is up to you.

To that extent 'looks ok' is fine, though I'd tweak its descriptive wording to be "this question is of satisfactory quality." because thats what the review queue is asking it to be judged on.