# Wrong reason given to close question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I am referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928558/finding-the-older-version-of-jsfiddle-by-entering-new-version-like-200) I have some problem in the jsfiddle so posted the question in stackoverflow. From the,stackoverflow jsfiddle wiki we can ask questions related to jsfiddle.But this question was closed as off the topic and following is the reason given

> This question appears to be off-topic for this site. While what’s on-
>   and off-topic is not always intuitive, you can learn more about it by
>   reading the help center. The users who voted to close gave this
>   specific reason:
>
> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite
>   off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to
>   attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem
>   and what has been done so far to solve it." – Łukasz L., Lee Taylor

I didnt not ask any one to find a tool for me.If a question is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945722/suggest-me-the-best-java-decompilers) then its 100% belongs to off the topic as the OP has clearely mentioned to find `decompiler`. But in my case I didn't not ask to find a tool/jar/library just wanted to know how to view the older version.

Comment: Only 2 people closed it as a tool request.  3 more voted to close as `This question appears to be off-topic because it is about jsFiddle`.  And I agree.  This sounds more like a support question for jsfiddle than a programming problem

Comment: @psubsee2003 what can be a programmatic question in jsfiddle?As my question is related to jsfiddle so I asked

Comment: And 2 people agree with you since they voted to reopen.  I just don't happen to agree.  This just seems more like a support question than a question about using jsfiddle, so the developers of jsfiddle would be more likely to be able to answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 what kind of questions can be asked in jsfiddle tag?

Comment: I agree that the close reason provided was terrible and inaccurate, but I still believe this question is off-topic. The community here at Stack Overflow can't possibly know why your versions have stopped loading. That's really something you should contact their developers about.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for your comment.I feel relaxed now because a moderator(you) is in my side.I also agree that the question is off topic but the reason was not accurate.So should I delete the question.If I delete that question will be banned from posting question or banning is applicable to deleteing downvoting questions

Comment: @javaBeginner, please stop posting comments for me to view. I don't know what you want me to do? As everyone else says above the close **reason** is inaccurate, but the close itself is valid. So, don't re post the question as it will still be off topic. Contact jsFiddle. It's their problem.

Comment: @Liam yes I agree that my questions will be off topic but the reason is not accurate.Moreover you have mentioned this if off topic because it is about jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes I have! and @animuson and psubedee2003 both agree with me. The more accurate close reason was the one that I added. *This question appears to be off-topic because it is about jsFiddle*. Take it on the chin and move on.

Comment: @Liam I got donvotes for 2 answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108886/if-i-hit-http-localhost80000000-it-takes-me-to-google-search/19108910#19108910 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928558/finding-the-older-version-of-jsfiddle-by-entering-new-version-like-200 Is that you who downvoted?

Comment: Emphatically, **No**! Bored of this conv now. I've made my point. Stop hassling me. I've got work to do.

Comment: @Liam Yes same here,you started the discussion first so you have to end

Comment: @animuson out of curiosity, are you able to see all 5 close votes?  Where there 3 votes for the custom reason and 2 for "recommendation"?  Or was there a different mix.

Comment: @psubsee2003 it doesn't matter because custom close reason will never show in the close banner as far as I know even if all five have chosen the same custom reason.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I know, but that's what I was trying to confirm.  In fairness to the OP here, the current design for this is somewhat confusing because it makes it look like the primary close reason was as a tools question and not something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> From the,stackoverflow jsfiddle wiki we can ask questions related to jsfiddle.

Yes, that's true. It's like with questions about every other IDE.

> But this question was closed as off the topic and following is the reason given...

We already established that the reason is the wrong one.

> I ... just wanted to know how to view the older version.

Actually, you did not want to know how to view old versions (which might be on topic), you wanted to know why viewing of the old version of this does not work. That question is off-topic, or at least not a good fit, on SO because we can't answer this question. These versions do no seem to be available anymore on the jsfiddle servers, so the question "why" would be better directed at the jsfiddle support.

Also, as I already said, those comments of yours do not belong in the question itself, but in this very Meta question, as they add *nothing* to the question on SO.

Comment: actually i wanted to know how.But if if i did this way tons of downvoting will be poured in asking *show us the code what have you tried for*

Comment: @javaBeginner the question you asked seems to be on-topic for webapps.SE.  In fact, this seems that someone has asked [something similar there](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36809/see-previous-and-subsequent-versions-of-a-jsfiddle-page)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks for this,I would have upvoted if this was an answer but unfortunately its a comment and you will not gain if i upvote.Still +1 for the info

Comment: @javaBeginner it doesn't answer your question here, so it is not much than a comment, but thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Based on your now reverted edits on your original question, and the comment chain on that question (that hopefully will be cleaned up soon), you seem to have a view that the presence of a tag (and the description in the tag wiki) are evidence that questions are on-topic.

Well, that is not a true statement.  With only 500 rep needed to create a tag, bad tags are created frequently, and once a tag is created, there is nothing to stop someone from creating a tag wiki (except 3 reviewers).   In fact the presence of another similar question is not even evidence that a question is on-topic as that question might not have been closed yet.

On-topic questions are still based on the ["What to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What not to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) sections of the help center.

Your question, while it is about a software tools commonly used by programmers, fails the final criterion for "what can I ask":

> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development

The reason is it is not answerable.  The only person that can reasonably answer that question is a developer for the particular tool because you aren't asking how you can see older versions, you are asking why you can't see a specific version.  This makes it a support question and better suited for the developers for jsfiddle.

---

You also seem to be hung up on the fact that the question was closed for the wrong reasons.  In that sense, you are only partially correct.  It takes 5 votes to close a question (and it is 5 votes for any reason, not 5 votes for the same reason).  Because of that there are frequently conflicts in what the close reason should be.  Normally the majority rules so you'll never see a close reason with just 1 or 2 votes unless it was the most selected reason.

In your case only 2 close voters actually picked the "Recommendation" close reason.  3 other people appear to have picked a **slightly** more accurate custom close reason "This question is off-topic because it is about jsfiddle."  Since both of the selected reasons are sub-categories under the "Off-topic" close reason, you are shown both.  And because the majority reason is a custom close reason, it is not shown in the banner message, but instead in the comments.

But in the end, the question still needs to be closed as it is not on-topic and the community has shown a preference to leaving questions closed with incorrect reasons as the effort to reopen an question and reclose it with the correct reason is better spent in other moderation tasks (such as the 91K+ questions in the close vote queue).

If you ever encounter a post that is closed for a reason that is just so off-the-wall wrong, you can flag it for a moderator's attention and explain that it should be closed for a different reason.  NOTE: This question, I don't think qualifies since it close reason, while not accurate, is not dangerously misleading.  Usually the best use case for flagging to change close reasons is when it closed as a duplicate of a post that is not even close to being a duplicate, but the post still should be closed.

Answer (score 3):

So I closed this question with the close reason:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about jsFiddle

Now lets be clear:

- I agree that the close reason *recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource* is wrong
- I did not vote for this close reason
- My close reason was as above and I believe this is a perfectly valid reason.
- The consensus of this thread is that the close reason I added (above) is valid and the actual close reason cited on the question is wrong
- Either way you cut it. This question is off topic and should be closed

I don't think you have a leg to stand on in this regard. The question could (I suppose) be reopened and then closed again. This would simply be a waste of everyone's time.

My advice, calmn down, stop making a fuss about this, delete the question to get your rep back (there may be consequences but in your instance I doubt that) and contact jsFiddle with your issue.

Comment: i dont agree *but I believe you downvoted one of my questions in revenge.* You are not only who have voted to close and alone you can not do anything,yes you can downvote(which you did) but you alone have not the power to close.If i wanted to take revenge then I would have downvoted to all the five users who have voted to close.If no body has said anything then this means I have not downvoted to anyone.One more thing I dont think this is a answer for this question,it should be a comment ofcourse so I am downvoting

Comment: Last sentence is wrong and misleading: "delete the question to get your rep back" - **there are consequences**, see question ban!!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Deleting one question will not bring down consequences, no?

Comment: @Liam for this user no, but for others that see this answer in the future, then maybe.  One question won't cause a ban, but it certain can push someone over the edge

Comment: @Liam deleting downvoted question has big impact, more than just the downvotes - so yes, for a user on the edge it can send him down to the pit.

Comment: @psubsee2003, I don't understand that? *for others that see this answer in the future*. Could you explain?

Comment: Ok, so to argue my point a little further. @ShaWizDowArd, and this user is on the edge?

Comment: @Liam that specific user no but Meta, like Stack Overflow, get many visitors and users reading the answers and they might understand from your last sentence there are no consequences which is wrong.

Comment: @Liam While you might be answering the OP's question, answers even on Meta are supposed to have value for some future visitor.  Advocating a possibly harmful action without mentioning the possible consequences does not make for a good answer with future value.

Comment: Ok, ok, point taken! :)

Comment: Cheers, now it's not (or at least much less) confusing. :)