# I didn't get the lost reputation points in serial downvoting back

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, down-votes, serial-voting

I have been getting downvotes for the last few days. I think this is the handiwork of a single user, because all the downvotes are for different questions and the downvoting time differs hardly 1 minute. I got a downvote on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417930/what-is-the-purpose-of-bootstrap-customize) on 21:39 and then on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811798/how-to-make-input-fields-editable) on 21:40 and on this time I got downvote on [this third question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633353/how-to-pass-the-checked-values-of-checkbox).

I think this is [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) and so I should be getting back the reputation points back but three days has already been passed and I didn't get it back.

Also, I got five downvotes to [this fourth question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928558/finding-the-older-version-of-jsfiddle-by-entering-new-version-like-200) and a moderator has deleted this, but after deletion also I didn't get back the lost reputation points. What is the explanation?

Please see the screenshot for downvoting times and the downvotes are always for different questions.

[image]

Comment: @downvoters please give a reason for downvoting.Is this off the topic?Am I wrong anywhere?Am I allowed to get back the repuatations?Is it good to downvote randomly?

Comment: have you considered these downvotes may be justified?

Comment: Either because "I think this is the handiwork of a single user" or because this is the second time you've posted about it today. Actually, it's probably both.

Comment: @Michael downvotes may be justified but serial downvoting i dont think so,After posting a question here I got downvotes to other questions

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn That was a different question.I blamed a particular person and now I do not blame anyone.

Comment: @javaBeginner how do you know they are of a single user rather than multiple users downvoting them?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn If I get downvotes regularly then I may be banned from posting questions.So this is what scares me.If my questions are bad then I deserve downvotes but some one giving intentional downvotes and for that i will be banned from posting questions is really bad

Comment: @Michael Its because downvotes are for different question.A single user can not downvote a question more than one time.Also downvoting time(clock) gives me hint.

Comment: The downvotes yesterday are too far apart to be related. The first two may have been by one user, but that doesn't yet make it a serial downvote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well my point of asking is if I get a lot of downvotes then I will be banned from posting questions.If I get a downvote then I loose 2 reps but If I get a upvote then I get 5 which far more.Only moderators can tell whether its a case of single or multiple users thats why i raised a question here.but unfortunately here also downvotes

Comment: @javaBeginner: Then you perhaps need to be more careful about what kind of questions you ask? Do your research first, and share your research in your questions you do ask. Good questions receive more upvotes than they receive downvotes.

Comment: @javaBeginner: and by posting on Meta you do risk attracting the Meta effect; more scrutiny towards your questions from experienced users can *also* lead to downvotes.

Comment: "Only moderators can tell whether its a case of single or multiple users thats why i raised a question here." I'm curious as to how you arrived at that logic.

Comment: *"If my questions are bad then I deserve downvotes"* <-- After reading several questions that were downvoted, I can't say your questions are 'good'. I am not talking about spelling errors or non-native-speaking-english-grammar, but about lack of research and a total lack of 'attempts' in your questions. Notable exceptions are [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20015880/2209007) and [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868490/what-are-the-different-eclipse-shortcuts-available) that might be more on-topic for SuperUser than for StackOverflow.

Comment: @MartijnPieters meta effect means?

Comment: @javaBeginner [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/165773 "what's this") means "Increase of voting activities observed in main site posts that have been exposed at meta..."

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think meta is for asking questions if something unsual you find in SO but your comment seems that asking questions in meta is more problem then in SO

Comment: @javaBeginner no, the Meta Effect can also have a positive impact to.  It all depends on the quality of your posts in general.  Good questions get upvotes, bad questions get downvotes.  All the Meta Effect does is attract more views, which lead to users judging the quality of your post and vote appropriately.

Comment: @javaBeginner `Well my point of asking is if I get a lot of downvotes then I will be banned from posting questions.` -> if this is the only reason you are concerned, then you probably don't have much to worry about.  With 3K rep, it will be extremely difficult for you to get banned.

Comment: @psubsee2003 your comment is really helpful.Well in meta experienced person are there some having more than 30 years of IT experience.And I am having 3 months of experience.Well in this question I have already said that I didnt find any method in twilio api still people downvote because I didnt not show any reseacrh effect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874860/is-there-any-way-to-send-sms-using-twilio-at-a-later-time

Comment: @psubsee2003 If you right that I will not get banned then i will never ask these type of questions in meta

Comment: @javaBeginner I never said you won't.  I can't say that because I don't know what actually triggers the ban (no one does except for devs).  But based on experience, your positive contributions so far should make it extremely difficult for you to get banned.

Comment: With your amount of reputation, the chance of being question banned on Stack Overflow is so slim to be practically impossible.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy why do people downvote on my questions why not on answers also.Does downvoting on answers not applicable for meta effect

Comment: @javaBeginner: because downvoting answers costs them reputation - they don't lose reputation for downvoting questions.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy yes thats true,asking questions here is severe down effect.Downvoters are downvoting only for fun.If i am not good in asking questions then I am also not good in answering,so I deserve downvote in answers too

Comment: As for deserving downvotes on answers: please [provide proper attribution if you copy examples from other sites](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19740616/revisions).

Comment: Adding to the meta effect: you lost 430 rep on Nov 2 because of user removal. If you had 100k+ rep this wouldn't be that suspicious, but you don't. It certainly shines a negative light on your profile.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel you have a careers profile.Well why is that for?Is it for getting jobs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first question of yours.

> What is the purpose of bootstrap customize?

That seems a bit off-topic, why? Because it is not generally related to coding. You're not showing any code, any search results that you have while you searched for answers. So a question that is off-topic gets downvotes. Or should I say, heavy downvotes. But that is not meant for off-topics only it is for duplicates and all other kind of questions too.

> how to make input fields editable?

In this question, you're a bit puzzling. However this question must not be downvoted.

> how to pass the checked values of checkbox

But this question is just the same (or lets say, somehow similar) to the last question. That is why, this one is getting a downvote.

Coming to your points, this much fast voting can be casted by a single user. Three events that happened between `21:39 - 21:40` are more likely to be an articraft of a single user should I say. However, you might want to wait the deleted post with downvotes will generate rep soon (well, it generates rep for me once moderator deletes a post with downvotes after a few minutes).

You have tagged a question for `serial voting` but have you read the answer? The answer is clear that the serial voting is meant to be voting on **many** post. These 3 posts won't be counted in many.

If that was a serial voting (down or up) system would have jumped into the fight and provided you with the rep that you have right on and would have punished the user doing so. Since system is well-aware of basic algorithms to conclude which one is a serial and which one is fair voting it took no action.

**Edition to answer**

I came to one more point for you. The server at SE keeps you network information too, using that system it will note when a user upvotes your questions or downvotes. By using this algorithm it will take action and do what it thinks should be done! So don't worry, this might be a co-incident by 2 - 3 users downvoting your questions which were in the active tab all at a time. Sorry about this, but this is also a condition here.

Try to read the basic posts about posting the questions and answers on SE

#### Links to read:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (How to stay on topic)

https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask (What should not be asked here)

https://stackoverflow.com/about (Go to the **Get answers to ...** section)

Comment: much fast voting can also be due to [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/165773 "what's this"), as time wise it followed [prior post at MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207172/165773). "Increase of voting activities observed in main site posts that have been exposed at meta..." Double-downvotes in quick succession are [known trick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178703/165773) of expressing personal dislike that [avoids detection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147374/165773).

Comment: "you're a bit puzzling" - as in unclear? That **is** grounds for downvoting - downvote popup: "This question does not show any research effort; it is **unclear** or not useful".

Comment: True, this isn't always a serial up or down voting it might be because of unclear question or answer too ..

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan **So don't worry, this might be a co-incident by 2 - 3 users downvoting your questions which were in the active tab all at a time. Sorry about this, but this is also a condition here.** means what?

Comment: Sadly but it means that when a user goes to the default page of the site, he gets to see the questions that are on the active tab which has a latest activity. So that might be a reason for this much hurriedly downvote, server would know the best answer..you can contact the team at http://stackoverflow.com/contact they will help you at best! :)