# Is there any way we can encourage people to explain delete votes?

Tags: feature-request, voting, vote-to-delete

If I were to cast the most annoying feature of Stack Overflow, I would say **delete vote** definitely. I probably can understand the design logic behind it, e.g., as [When should I vote to delete a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete-a-question) explains, **too broad** or **opinion-based** or **not helpful**. But the problem is quite often, these criteria themselves are opinion-based! I will use my experience to show my points.

I asked the question [How do I prevent Scrum from turning great developers into average developers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/410482/how-do-i-prevent-scrum-from-turning-great-developers-into-average-developers) When I first asked it, I was fully prepared that it may be closed as too broad or opinion-based, or to some agile advocate, totally non-sense. But to my surprise it became quite popular and I got 220 up-votes.

After that I asked a related question about management for agile team. It was not only closed but also deleted (so I can not show its link now)! Because I live in China I guess my question was closed and deleted when I slept. So to me it was a total surprise that the next day I checked my question, it was gone!

Two days before I asked a similar question about management for agile team, [How to manage the team effectively on a self-managing team?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/431284/how-to-manage-the-team-effectively-on-a-self-managing-team) It was once again closed and got delete votes. But because of my last experience I re-edited my question before it got more delete votes. So my question was re-opened.

So I would strongly suggest that if someone casts a delete vote, they should at least have the courtesy to explain why. And better not just with a simple word like *too broad / opinion-based*. I will argue those words maybe good enough for close votes, but not for delete votes.

So is there any way to that, maybe in the next release?

---

As John Omielan commented, be specific about how. I would suggest each delete voter to give a reason, choose from some canned options or write their own. I would also argue the canned options better not be "too broad / opinion-based". Those reasons maybe good enough for close votes, but not for delete votes.

The bottom line is that the person who asked a question may have put a lot time/effort in preparing and asking the question. If you want to delete it, at least show the courtesy to explain why.

---

My question has got 10 down-votes so far; if it follows the trajectory of what typically happens in other Stack Exchange websites, it is quite possible it would be closed and deleted. Why doesn't the meta site have close votes & delete votes? Why is meta more tolerated? Is this a feature or a bug?

And let me give another example of my own question to show why I strongly argue delete votes should be used cautiously.

My question [Does OOP overemphasize the importance of noun and thus put action/verb in the less importance position ？](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/419122/does-oop-overemphasize-the-importance-of-noun-and-thus-put-action-verb-in-the-le) was closed and got 2 delete votes. But it also got 2 reopen votes and 5 up-votes. Just judging from the length of my question, you can see I put a lot of time and effort to prepare and ask this question, so I begged in my question that future readers do not vote to delete it.

---

Someone suggested my question maybe duplicated of [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin), but I don't think so as down-vote and delete-vote are totally different. Just take this question as an example, I have got 13 down-votes so far. But I don't mind and I definitely don't need an explanation for those down-votes because I understand people don't agree with my suggestion. But if it were deleted I would definitely be upset and want to see an explanation why!

I can give another reason. The result of deleting a question, especially for the future reader, is the question never exists, people never have such question. But the down-vote or close-vote at least show people do have such doubt even though other have closed it or down-voted it.

Comment: Explanations are usually given when closing.

Comment: Why can't you use the per site meta to ask for clarification if a post got actively deleted by delete votes? Much more productive then "encouraging" delete voters to leave a comment. Don't make the life of curators more troublesome by optimizing the experience of an individual user.

Comment: That is actually my whole question is about, delete vote (not close vote)

Comment: How many delete votes do those two questions have?

Comment: 3 delete votes can delete a question. So I guess my first deleted question got 3, the second question got 1.

Comment: If you want to delete a question, which someone may put a lot of effort/time in asking (my case), can't you at least have the courtesy to explain why ?

Comment: That first question was never closed so it couldn't have taken delete votes. For the other one you got plenty of comments already what users found not useful in your question and your edit obviously solved that issue as it got re-openend. Your examples don't support the feature you're requesting here.

Comment: @Qiulang Welcome to Meta SE. You used the tag [tag:feature-request], but I'm not clear on what you actually want to have changed. Is it to somehow require each delete voter to give a comment and, if so, how is this to be implemented (e.g., they can choose from some canned options or write their own)? Please be specific.

Comment: "That first question was never closed so it couldn't have taken delete votes." I don't understand. The question was deleted for sure.

Comment: @Qiulang please share link to the deleted question, many here do have 10k on SO and can see it.

Comment: The timeline doesn't show it: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/431284/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 I don't know where to find my deleted question.

Comment: @rene  "Why can't you use the per site meta to ask for clarification " I don't know I can do that. How ?

Comment: @Qiulang If you click on your Questions tab, there should be a "recently deleted questions" link at the bottom. Clicking on this will show you the list of your questions deleted within the last 60 days.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I know that but my question was deleted longer than 60 days.

Comment: I remember I asked that not long after my "popular" scrum question , maybe by the encouragement of that.  So you can image what a surprise I had when it was deleted.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I updated my question to "be specific" about my feature request. Thanks

Comment: As for meta: ask here: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/ and read https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta before posting there

Comment: @JohnOmielan I added another update to make my point, please take a look.

Comment: That new example might have gotten two re-open votes but in the end [three reviewers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/227819) voted *leave closed*. You still haven't provided a strong case for your feature request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin) Delete votes are just as anonymous as downvotes, so the same reasoning holds in this case as well.

Comment: @Luu Delete votes are *not* anonymous if the post actually ends up being deleted, so there's some differences there

Comment: @Medix2 true, but only if you know where to look, which leaves it anonymous for 99% of the users I guess.

Comment: @rene I feel we are not on the same page at all. Besides, all my examples, the new example included, were trying to show delete vote was unreasonable, they were not about close vote or re-open vote.

Comment: @Luuklag that one did not answer my question at all. Just take this question as an example, I have got 13 down-votes. But I don't mind at all because I understand people don't agree with my suggestion. But if it were deleted I would definitely upset and how to see an explanation why!

Comment: I added another update to my question, please take a look.

Comment: All votes are reasonable, including delete votes.

Comment: "I begged in my question that future readers do not vote to delete it" - you shouldn't do that. That's meta-commentary, or to put it more simply, noise. It doesn't belong in your question. To be perfectly honest, I'm surprised that nobody's removed it before now.

Comment: 'begged in my question that future readers do not vote to delete it' AKA 'I know it's a bad question but I want an answer anyway because I don't care about the site policy/rules'.  That, alone, would have guaranteed a delete vote from me had I read the question:(

Comment: @MartinJames Delete votes should have a purpose and it shouldn't be to punish people who don't care. It should be to remove content that doesn't fit at all. An alternative would be to simply remove meta commentary from content, downvote and move on.

Comment: @Trilarion deletion is not punishment.  If I vote and something gets deleted, a file gets flagged on a server somewhere.  The file is not even erased - it can be undeleted.  The loss of treasure from having a boolean swapped, in some SE database is not any kind of 'punishment' that requires further action/s above those already available.

Comment: @Trilarion 'Delete votes should have a purpose and it shouldn't be to punish people who don't care. It should be to remove content that doesn't fit at all' maybe, maybe not - I don't care.

Answer (score 6):

Delete votes on questions, [properly used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), should be for **one** reason:

> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be deleted.

There should be no need to pick a reason, because there would only be one reason available.

Since only closed questions can be deleted by non-moderators, the main problem with the question should already have been articulated when the question was closed.  A delete vote simply says that, in addition to the reason the question was closed, the question does not provide lasting value by remaining on the site.

---

<sup>Fine print: "no lasting value" is often interpreted broadly to include things that are completely outside the site's scope, even if they might be of value on a site about that topic.</sup>

Comment: "Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be deleted." That sounds very subjective. Especially the "value" thing. I could even argue that many things that aren't even closed have no lasting value (or something really close to zero). Maybe that section should be a bit expanded to get more close to the fine print: "Is completely outside the site's scope" or similar.

Comment: @Trilarion this is one of my arguments too, it is too subjective to be the reason to delete a question.

Comment: The problem is, to own experience, it is NOT properly used.

Comment: I'm not sure the solution to people misusing the delete feature is to make them explain their misuse of it. Perhaps a better solution would be to encourage them to allow the question to be edited into shape before voting to delete.

Comment: Hi I can give you another example, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/419122/does-oop-overemphasize-the-importance-of-noun-and-thus-put-action-verb-in-the-le  this question was closed, got 2 delete votes. But it also got 2 reopen votes and 5 up-votes. I begged in my question that future reader do not vote to delete it.

Comment: @RyanM "I'm not sure the solution to people misusing the delete feature is to make them explain their misuse of it." It's not a complete solution, but a good start. If you cannot explain the decision, it may be wrong. The complete solution would be reviews of delete votes like we do for close votes.

Answer (score 5):

Only users with at least 20k rep (the [trusted user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) privilege) can cast delete votes right after a question is closed, and only if the question scores -3 or lower. (10k users must wait two days, as must 20k users if the question scores -2 or higher.)

And to be honest, I don't think user with 20k rep, who is very familiar with the site and rules (well, should be) need any encouragement to post a comment, they're well aware they can leave such a comment.

I do understand it's frustrating to have your questions deleted, but that's just part of how Stack Exchange sites work, for good and for bad.

Comment: Let me just use this question as an example, so far it has got 4 down-votes (out of 17 total times) so an educated guess is my question/feature request is non-helpful/stupid, which I don't mind too much. But if it were then deleted I definitely feel upset and think the delete vote doesn't make sense at all. Thankfully this site doesn't have delete vote.

Comment: Are there deletion reasons (like for close votes close reasons)? Maybe they could act as explanation.

Comment: No that is why I am asking this question.

Comment: @Qiulang the question is neither non-helpful nor stupid. People just disagree with what you suggest. And I agree it should not be deleted, it's a totally valid feature request.

Comment: @Trilarion no. deletion has no GUI like closing a question. Just a "Are you sure?" confirmation, and if you confirm, delete vote is being cast. You'll see for yourself soon enough. ;-)

Comment: We have a small, active subset of the community on Softwareengineering.SE having more than 20K rep, but never leaving a specific comment for the tons of close votes and downvotes they cast (at best a canned comment). Not that they should be forced to comment, but I think the argument in this answer is weak.