# Highly voted question with great answer marked for deletion

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I have a question that has many (60) upvotes and an incredible answer that has 70 up votes.  It has been marked as a duplicate and has 3 deletion marks against it.

What will happen to the question if more people vote to delete it?

I flagged the question for moderator attention to say that the great answer should be saved if possible, but there is no visible change in over a week.

Comment: Is this the question you're talking about? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/best-way-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, but I didnt want to link it to encourage someone to take action on it before a general discussion happened.

Comment: Well, it's a pretty lame attempt at hiding it since you're just asking people to go to your profile and look for that question.

Comment: In any case, it should either stay undeleted, or merged. I dunno what's with all the trigger happy people lately. There's been way too much insta-deleting of questions from new users, dupes, and anything they don't like - regardless of how good it is. (I'm not talking about non-constructive or bike-shed questions, but actual *real* questions that are falling victim to those who misuse their 10k powers.)

Comment: It looks like Shog is playing with it right now. So it looks like those answers will stay. :)

Comment: You can also go and reaccept the top answer. It seems that all the merging and unmerging has inadvertently removed the tick.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I originally flagged that question asking for a merge over two years ago. So my first impulse was to merge it.

But the obvious choice for merging had a rather less comprehensive answer. So I repented of my error, closed the older question as a duplicate of yours, and merged the other direction.

Also, [a reminder for folks voting to delete this stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50069/why-are-we-deleting-instead-of-merging):

> I wish people wouldn't delete questions with good answers. You're destroying the useful contributions of your peers!
>
> ### Flag these for moderator attention instead and suggest a merge!

Comment: Flag these for moderator attention and suggest a merge, you say? Well I know someone who flagged a question and asked for a merge, and had to wait 2 years for the merge to happen...

Comment: To be fair, no one in their right mind listens to *that guy*.

Comment: hehe ... right.