# Is "Can you be terrible at math and still be a great programmer" historically relevant, or old and off-topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, historical-lock

I found this question a few days ago and was a little curious about whether it should have a historical lock or just be closed in the usual fashion.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50529/can-you-be-terrible-at-math-and-still-a-great-programmer

[image]

It is currently "protected", but it doesn't have a historical notice. I'm thinking it would be considered wildly off-topic and/or primarily opinion based by today's standards.

Should it be closed or should a historical lock be added?

Comment: Or maybe deleted?

Comment: The historic lock message starts out with "*This question exists because it has historical significance*". Can it be argued that this question has significance? I'm not so sure. It doesn't really seem to add much to the site IMO.

Comment: @Geobits, while it has some significance, the most important factor is that is helps people search for it find the dupe.  Stack Exchange has a policy of not deleting dupes.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Thanks for the quick edit

Comment: @apaul34208, sure, in the future it'd probably be best not to bring up these kind of questions on Meta, since the rogue deletionists are always looking for questions to kill.

Comment: @LanceRoberts If these questions aren't brought to Meta, dissenting opinions might not be heard. While I'm not sure if I agree with your position, I think the discussion is worth having.

Answer (score 18):

Thanks for bringing that up.

I've deleted it because reasons:

- 5 years old, only 11,000 views
- The 'duplicate' was also deleted
- Nothing of value is lost by deleting that question; i[t isn't as if no one has ever asked that question in the history of the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=Can%20you%20be%20terrible%20at%20math%20and%20be%20a%20good%20programmer&oq=Can%20you%20be%20terrible%20at%20math%20and%20be%20a%20good%20programmer&aqs=chrome..69i57.5452j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8).
- It's attracted answers in the last year that just fuel the perception that we allow these sorts of questions.
- We have an [authoritative question that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157354/is-mathematics-necessary-for-programming) (even though it's off topic for the site), has more votes, views, and traction than this question. It even has *a little* value. This one has none of that.

If there were a *possibility* of useful content being deleted, I wouldn't delete the question. In this case, there really isn't.  If you want an example of a question that has useful content (and is a duplicate, yay!), how about this one:

> [Is Mathematics necessary for programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157354/is-mathematics-necessary-for-programming)

I could conceivably delete all the answers on the question I deleted and merge the two questions, but that's a lot of work for little gain.

Comment: That was completely wrong to do George.  At the least you should have let the community delete it.  It's immoral for moderators to do that unilaterally in a way that the community can't reverse.  You could have just locked it.

Comment: Shouldn't it have been closed as a duplicate of the deleted duplicate's duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157354/is-mathematics-necessary-for-programming

Comment: You guys never cease to amaze me... very efficient.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel We can't close as a duplicate of a deleted question, and it's really not worth even keeping it around.  We'll always have <strike>Paris</strike> question 157354.

Comment: Stack Exchange has a policy of not deleting dupes, reiterated many times over.

Comment: Can I request a screen shot or even just a block-quote of the now deleted question so that my question still makes sense?

Comment: @Lance So if there's *two* bad questions, they're worth keeping around? No...

Comment: @apaul34208: http://i.imgur.com/I41SG3g.png

Comment: @LanceRoberts Locking a question is an action that the community can't reverse either. There's nothing *immoral* about an elected moderator using their mod powers to clean up the site. It's what we're here for. This is a duplicate *of a deleted question*. Nothing of value is lost in deleting it too.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, locking still leaves it visible to viewers and the search engine.  It's is immoral when mods of his experience know that it is against policy, and decide that they are above that.  We just lost one more search vector to the duped question by a mod's unilateral decision.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: but the deleted question in its turn is a duplicate of a locked question. This means that this question is a duplicate of the locked question. In the end, doesn't this mean that the deleted question should've just been locked/merged?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The deleted question is a duplicate of a question that is closed, not locked.  It also has 7 delete votes. http://stackoverflow.com/q/157354/1288

Comment: @apaul34208 We don't normally take this sort of action if the action can be seen as controversial. In this case, I can't find *any* reason for this question to still exist.  That's rare for me.

Comment: Your authoritative question has 9 delete votes already... (edit: 10 seconds later just been deleted).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards It's solely because of its votes and views that I haven't deleted the 'authoritative question'.  That's a bit more controversial than the question in question.

Comment: I'm confused; both the questions you quote as being better versions (if still dodgy) are deleted

Comment: @LanceRoberts There is no global policy that duplicate questions should never be deleted.  Rather there is a policy that some duplicates have value when kept around, and some don't, so they should be evaluated more carefully when considering deletion.  They shouldn't be deleted if they are likely to be a window into the canonical question.  Not all duplicates end up being such windows.  Those that don't serve to effectively direct traffic to the canonical question, nor have valuable content themselves, can most certainly be deleted.  That is in no way contrary to policy.

Comment: @RichardTingle The 'authoritative' question was deleted seconds ago by the community.  If it looks like it's going to do multiple trips along the 'delete/undelete' route and cause issues, I'll put a moderator delete vote to keep it from yo-yoing back and forth.  I'd be surprised if there are 11 people who wish to undelete such a question, however.

Comment: Ah, there is nothing so dangerous to a question as being mentioned on meta

Comment: It's now up to 4 undelete votes for the dupe, hope we can make it.

Comment: @Servy, please don't try to confuse new people with inaccurate information.  Duplicates that use different enough wording in the title like that question did are important for the search engine to find the duped question, and that has been pointed out on Meta many times over.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, that would also be immoral.

Comment: Are you really undeleting and reopening any old crap just to make a point @LanceRoberts? Just because it didn't follow what you consider to be the proper process? Or do you really think that post is of great lasting value?

Comment: @LanceRoberts That's precisely what our role is: to intervene in contentious issues. It doesn't mean our action is permanent.

Comment: Are questions that yo-yo not more usually locked?

Comment: By putting a mod delete vote in @George your stopping people from having their say... does it matter if it yo-yos? If you think it does wouldn't it be better to lock it rather than stop people from expressing their opinion and create yet another meta-storm about an off-topic question that while somewhat interesting isn't really worth that much.

Comment: @RichardTingle I'd be willing to lock it while a discussion about whether it should be kept around is on meta -- but the only way for that to happen is for some (moderator/group) to take an action that generates that discussion. Pre-emptively undeleting it and locking it for historical reasons would be out of bounds since it doesn't clearly warrant a historical lock (even though it's more valuable than the other questions we've talked about, it doesn't have indispensible information in it that would warrant a historical lock).

Comment: @LanceRoberts That's exactly what I was discussing.  Some duplicates end up being more effective search targets than their canonical versions, and thus keeping them around can provide value.  *Not all duplicate questions do this though*.  Many duplicates are quite a bit less searchable than their canonical questions, use similar terms, etc.  Over time this can even be measured objectively by looking at the numbers of views that it has referred.  If a question isn't effectively directing traffic, it doesn't have that type of value.  On top of that, if the canonical is deleted, what's the point?

Comment: "We have an authoritative question ..." Not any more, the deletionists got to it. How about putting a historical lock on it? Especially if you're going to use it as support for deleting the other. And since it's about to turn into a deletion war.

Comment: @Kevin If it successfully gets undeleted by the community, and it looks like it's going to yo-yo back and forth, we'll talk about it. Right now it doesn't look like it has the support to be even undeleted, let alone considered for Historical locking.  Not to mention that even as 'popular' as that question is (which isn't really popular compared to questions that qualify for historical locks), I can't point to any indispensible information in that question that would warrant a historical lock.  It's one of those things that would need to be fleshed out by the community on meta.

Comment: The P.SE version of that question - [Do you have to be good at math to be a good programmer?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/89158/do-you-have-to-be-good-at-math-to-be-a-good-programmer) is also locked and closed (and a whopping 73k views)

Comment: @MichaelT 73K is a lot for Programmers, and a fair amount for SO, but not major by any means (not in 5 years).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I'd have to poke Data.SE to get the numbers, but I'd wager its in the top 1% of most hit questions. Its more a long the lines of "old question from the elder times that was better served at P.SE (in the elder times)."

Comment: @MichaelT It probably is -- but our threshold is pretty high for views to lock a question as 'historical significance'. If it had over 100K, that'd be pretty significant and would weigh more heavily.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker (I think my point is getting missed) - The SO version never was a good SO question once P.SE existed.  Furthermore, on a site that gets a *small* fraction of the traffic that SO gets, the P.SE version has 7x more hits than the SO version.  The SO version one *should* have been deleted 4 or 5 years ago in light of this.

Comment: @MichaelT Ah!  That makes more sense.  You're right, of course.  I am used to people arguing the other way, that because something has more than a few thousand views, it should stay around forever.

Answer (score 4):

This question is a perfect magnet for chatty and primarily opinion based answers. The fact that question is protected doesn't have anything to do with closing or locking, it's simply a barrier set to prevent new users to add their 2 cents.

It should be closed because it gives a bad example for new users.

Answer (score -18):

It was just deleted by George Stocker innapropriately and unilaterally.  It was a historical question that should have just been locked, and/or only deleted by community consensus.  Stack Exchange also has a policy of not deleting duplicates, re-iterated many times over the years.

One of the worst activities going on by mods on Stack Overflow is unilateral deletion that the community cannot do anything about.  **Please be careful when voting for mods to make sure they understand the ethics of their position.**

Comment: And how is the community supposed to delete a locked question? I agree with George, and if you disagree, comment on his post, but don't post a non-answer. He even provided a very convincing list of reasons for us. -1

Comment: @Doorknob, I realize you don't understand the issue here, but I've edited my answer to address that.

Comment: Regardless, this is a reply to George's answer, not the question above. Please don't post non-answers as answers.

Comment: @Doorknob, no, it's an answer, you may want to re-read it.

Comment: -1 Mods aren't doctors and to apply 'ethics' on their position is silly.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO No, they're more like judges/arbiters, where ethics *definitely* apply. I don't fully agree with Lance here, but there's nothing wrong with talking about moderator ethics.

Comment: @Geobits They're janitors and *ethics* have very little to do with their position.

Comment: Locks are for posts of *enormous* value to the community, despite being questions that meet the criteria for closure, or possibly even deletion.  This question is *not* of extremely high value.  It is in fact of extremely low value.  Locking it would be inappropriate.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO One can apply ethics to virtually anything and everything people do.

Comment: This answer doesn't address why the question is of high value to community, or even to itself. It only uses the "it's old, it cannot be deleted" logic.

Comment: @random, no, I added the "dupe" policy logic.

Comment: @LanceRoberts What's your source on that?  I would assert that there is no such policy that duplicates should never be deleted for any reason.  That is clearly your mis-interpretation of the policy.  And honestly, regardless of any previous sources, the community seems to have pretty clearly voiced **right here in this meta question** that they do *not* want to have such a policy, and that they clearly feel that it is appropriate to delete certain questions, even if they are closed as a duplicate.  If it wasn't the policy before (which it was) then it is *now*.

Comment: @Servy, you've been around long enough to know about the policy, and it would be very easy to find yourself.  For those new who want to see it in print, here is a reference to [merging instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50106/13295) and here is one on the direct [deletion of duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates).

Comment: @LanceRoberts Those are referencing *certain* duplicates that have either successfully shown to be useful search targets for canonical questions, or that had valuable answers.  This question is neither.  *If* a duplicate question has valuable answers or it is successfully directing traffic to a duplicate question, then it has value and shouldn't be deleted.  Neither applies here, so deletion is entirely justifiable.  Yes, I've been around for a while, and I know enough to know that the policy is that *valuable* duplicates should be kept while dups that are not valuable should not be.

Comment: From that last one's accepted answer *"As far as I'm concerned, only **off-topic** or unintelligible questions should be deleted"*. Emphasis mine. And the former refers to "useful" content. I'm not so sure that there is all that much of value in the deleted post. So not all that valuable, and certainly off-topic.

Comment: @Servy, I guess you weren't paying attention to all the comments and answers here.  The question was deleted when it's dupe was still alive.  The dupe was deleted later.  So the first question was deleted against policy.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Once again, no, it was not in violation of policy.  Your personal policy, maybe, site policy, no.  Next, it wasn't deleted before the duplicate it pointed to was.  The duplicate it pointed to was deleted first.  But it was closed as a duplicate of a question that was also closed as a duplicate.  The duplicate of the duplicate was what was deleted later.

Comment: @Servy FWIW, there's even an automatic clean up script that deletes duplicates. ([link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)) - the first two queries do not have a duplicate filter in them.