# Remove a vote-to-close on a question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, change-vote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

How can I remove a close vote (mine) on a question or is it simply not possible?

If it's not possible, why isn't it possible? We can negate down votes if the question has been edited appropriately, can't we change our mind about close votes?

This question is similar to the following question and answer provided.

> [How about a "Vote not to close" option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close) and [Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close/185#185)

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes

Comment: Votes expire after a couple of days so as long as the post doesn't get enough votes to close yours will drop off eventually.

Comment: @ChrisF: That I did not know. Idea for another question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I remove a close vote (mine) on a question or is it simply not possible?

It's not possible.

> If it's not possible, why isn't it possible?

Obviously this has been requested and declined: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/33949#33949)

Comment: I like how that has six down votes on it.

Comment: @Josh that's nothing, there's a post of Jeff's detailing some unpopular change with -39 votes last time I checked... I forgot where it is but it'll come to me again.