# Vote to un-close

Tags: feature-request, questions, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How about a “Vote not to close” option to counter the “Vote to close”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close)

A "vote to close" on an otherwise good question is like a black mark on its face.

Sometimes it will take a few weeks for a good question to close, because it takes that long for 5 silly people to find it.

So, how about an "*Un*-vote to close?"  I mean, its a vote that cancels a close request.

This way if 5 people want to close a question, but 30 would rather it remain open, the question can remain open without supermoderator intervention.

Comment: awww, nobody's up?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close

Comment: I see.  You are awake, Jon.

Comment: Vote to close, then.  Good for you! :D

Comment: :D Just checking in.