# Allow undelete votes before deletion occurs

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, 10k-tools, undelete

Like the feature-request that's out there to allow reopen votes to be cast simultaneously with close votes, let's allow undelete votes to be cast simultaneously with delete votes.

I've noticed a few posts in the 10k tools that I wouldn't want to see deleted (usually because of good answers or comments), but realize that I may miss them being deleted and slipping off of the recently deleted list, before I can vote to undelete.

Comment: isnt that declined for closed posts?

Comment: probably, but it's still a good idea

Comment: (+1) FYI: [How about a "Vote not to close" option to counter the "Vote to close"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/178179)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, we lack a communications mechanism here. User 1 can't see that user 2 flagged for moderation attention. User 3 can't wave a flag at user's 4, 5, 6, and 7 saying 'please don't shoot.'

We need some help from the devs if we really want to improve the quality of the delete decisions. I'm not especially in favor of just allowing a food-fight in the votes as opposed to actual text.

Like, perhaps, double-secret comments visible only to those with rep to delete?

Comment: Why bother with secrecy? If you want to post a comment, then post a comment - whether to argue for or against deletion.

Comment: @Shog9 not so much secrecy as 'there are already 100 contentious comments, it's a pain to go digging for evidence that someone has a good reason to hold off on delete.'

Comment: Heh... if there are 100 contentious comments, the reason had better be a pretty good one...

Comment: @Shog9 that line of argument did occur to me. *horse noise*

Answer (score 0):

This already exists: if you don't think a post should be deleted, then vote to re-open it. If it gets enough votes to be re-opened, then it won't be deleted.

In the case of duplicates, ask a moderator to merge. Yeah, merging has some serious down-sides, but for now it's the tool we have.

Comment: I don't think this is exactly right. There are questions that I want to stay closed, but don't want to see deleted. Duplicates with differently searchable titles, are one such category. I've been using the comments to indicate my preference in the matter, but it is not the ideal mechanism, especially if the comment in question is hidden by default.

Comment: I don't want it reopened. I want whatever useful answers it has to be merged to another question, and then ... I'm not sure if deletion or being left closed is what we're looking for.

Comment: @dmckee, @Rosinante: duplicates with useful answers are not handled well by the current system... Ideally, the question would be left closed as a "signpost" to guide searchers (auto-redirects would help as well...), but right now that's not easily possible. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/40346/allow-high-rep-users-to-migrate-answers-from-one-question-to-another and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/16437/when-merging-questions-leave-the-duplicate-one-as-a-placeholder as well as http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/50761/ - this problem is deeper than delete voting.

Comment: I have been voting to reopen, but like @dmckee, there are some I do feel need to stay closed, but shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: BTW-- I have been treating reopen votes as a flag to check carefully if it should be left undeleted.