# What is wrong with Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, deleted-questions, not-constructive

I posted a question a while back asking for Derby tutorials or screencasts, or any helpful material regarding the topic.

The question was promptly closed as "not constructive". Unlike other questions that were basically the same (on different subjects).

Over the past year that question received > 20 upvotes and was favourited multiple times. There was a discussion going on in the comments as to why the question had been closed.

Answers to this question would obviously have benefited other people besides me (I have long since decided not to use Derby).

A couple of days ago, a comment popped up that basically stated: "We can all turn to Quora, where this question has been answered".

Surprisingly, the question has now been deleted altogether.

Coincidence? I think not.

Comment: If you came for a discussion, why did you title the question with profanity?

Comment: I don't really care how many downvotes this question gets. Go ahead.

Comment: The [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375384/derby-tutorials-or-screencasts) in question (10k+ link)

Comment: Because I think this is ridiculous moderation. And it really bugs me. But for the sake of the discussion, I have removed it.

Comment: One thing that's seriously wrong with Stack Overflow is people trying to stretch the Q&A format to its limits and turn it into a free for all discussion forum. This is the one problem I have no idea how to solve, everything else is easily fixable.

Comment: Downvotes here mean people don't agree, as [mentioned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) in the meta faq.

Comment: If you want to understand the reasoning behind the closure and deletion of that question: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: Go take a nap, OP. BTW, we don't allow questions that seem like 'best practices' or 'polling' anymore.

Comment: Why would I take a nap in the middle of the day?

Comment: The question was posted at a time when there was close to no material on Derby to be found on the web. Where else would a programmer go to ask that question? Apparently I was not the only one looking on SO for an answer. If those types of questions are not wanted on SO, fine. But then moderators should follow a clear line. Commenters pointed to similar questions that were all fine. And I am not even discussing the fact that it was closed. I find it interesting that it was removed right after someone mentioned an answer to the question on Quora. That comment might actually have helped people.

Comment: @JosephTura I think you are a bit quick with your conclusions. The question might have had pending delete votes for a while, and just got the last one after the quora comment... Even assuming that it shouldn't have been deleted, it's extremely easy to undelete it, no need for the rant. All you needed to do is post a question saying: "Hey, this was deleted and I don't think it should be. Could someone explain to me why it was, and could we undelete it?"

Comment: There is rarely ever a need for a rant. That's their nature ;)

Let me rephrase, then: I find it mildly disturbing that SO makes it hard to comprehend the reasons behind the deletion of a question. And I still think that said comment might have provided a valuable helper to some people.

Sorry for making accusations that are probably wrong. Just bugged me.

Comment: @JosephTura A few discussions you might be interested in reading and contributing to: [How can we stop premature deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171763) (and [its followup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513)) and [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645). We can certainly do better when it comes to deletions.

Comment: @Yannis: Thank you, will read.

Comment: @yannis slant.co

Comment: @JosephTura: Because you are cranky.

Comment: @0A0D: That made me laugh. You are right. I was a bit cranky. Not anymore. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: @casperOne I think you are forgetting who first talked about slant.co in TL ;)

Comment: @Yannis Can't determine if it was you or Stocker who first mentioned it. I'm still fascinated by it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was right for the community to delete that question.  People searching for Derby tutorials through Google should **not** be directed to an old, unanswered, closed Stack Overflow question. They should be directed to Derby tutorials.  There's no reason for Stack Overflow to be inserted into the middle of that workflow when we don't have the answer here.

I closed the question after it sat unanswered for a full week after you posted it.  It was the kind of "shopping list" question specifically called out in the [Don't Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) section of the FAQ.

> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

"Other questions that are basically the same (on different subjects)" really do need to be closed. Please vote to close them when you see them so they're added to the [close queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/) for other users to review.

Comment: I can follow that argument. Thanks.