# Access to removed question

Tags: discussion, support

Please give me access to a question, that was removed.

Notice: If there is any technical support here, please redirect this message there, thank you very much.

I have asked a question here. It was removed. Ok. But next time, could you send me a message about it please.

But oops, it is not reachable under my account (on my account it says "0 questions" in my account, which is apparently a lie...)
So please, reveal a way that one can see his/her question which has been removed. Thank you very much.

Reasons:
There are reasons and you probably are not interested in reading them, but consider reading more, please...

1. I spent a very long time building that question
2. It's a slow-process to build your first question,
   you must:

   - complete registration.
   - overcome bad display of forms in Opera + there are some surprises in the page-flow (I would like to do something(ask a question), but your website wants me to do something else, to answer a question. Or during the filling of the question form it's not possible to fill tags, because the system thinks that those filled terms are one phrase (in Opera)).
   - And suppose, someone does not speak English as their first language, so he/she must make more effort to orient here.

And you find out (on second day), that your question was not under stackoverflow, but under *meta*stackoverflow (maybe there was an idea to clearly mark both as separate?)

- so it is easy pass the information, that you are not on main site, but on some sub-site ("meta-stackoverflow") - and that there are important and different contexts of the "ASK QUESTION" button...!!!

Hmm, thanks for understanding and your help ;-)

Comment: The question you had asked was off topic for this site. You should probably have posted it on [main], not here on Meta. It was also a question that is not suitable for Stack Overlow, so it was deleted. Please read the [main] FAQ to see what is and is not suitable there.

Comment: You do not have to make a registration, you can also ask questions withoug having a user account.

Comment: @Oded - So hang on a second.. if I understand correctly, OP asked a question on meta (it was meant for SO) and it was deleted instead of migrated? Is that the case? Shouldn't that have been *moved*?

Comment: @w4rumy - That's not the case for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Mike - The question was not a good fit for SO. It was a shopping question and would have been closed and deleted there - would that be a better outcome? A large amount of questions that are meant for SO that end up being posted on MSO are not good questions for SO. It is better they are closed and deleted without migration.

Comment: @Oded - Nope, that was the right call, I didn't know what the question was. Thanks for the info. ...your first comment is slightly misleading however, it would have been closed/deleted on SO as well os the fact that it was off topic for *meta* doesn't really matter

Comment: @Mike - the vast majority of people asking coding questions here on MSO are trying to get round a low quality question ban on SO, so no we don't (and indeed can't) migrate those questions.

Comment: While I agree the question should remain deleted, surely a mod can do the OP the favour and store his question somewhere in a JSFiddle or something.

Comment: @Oded - what does it mean "shopping question"?

Comment: I am recomended to FAQ. So faq stated "software tools commonly used by programmers". As I hear :-))) drupal, opencart and zend framework are very used by programmers as their tools as much as other frameworks/webcms I suppose to may be in answers.

Comment: @Jii - I refer to this blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: In regards to software tools - comparison questions are not a good match to Stack Overflow either. I refer you to this blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: related: **[suggestion for deletion grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171782/165773 "details here")** _"let people see their deleted questions if only for the first 48 hours after deletion. The links to them would still remain invisible to everyone else (except moderators)..."_

Answer (score 8):

I can state with near-certainty that your question will not be undeleted. Not only do Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow have a different style (the latter having more grays than the former), but the images in the upper-left-hand corner are clearly different:

[image: Meta Stack Overflow banner]

[image: Stack Overflow banner]

Also, after hitting the "Ask Question" button on Meta Stack Overflow, the following box can be found to the right of the textarea where the question is entered (the red ellipse is for emphasis only, of course):

[image]

No one tricked you into posting an inappropriate question on Meta Stack Overflow. You just need to pay more attention to what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you to you all for very much attention. @Jack Maney: If you will read twice slowly, you will find, that in first I would need the content of the question, that text (as I am lazy to build it second time, e.g. at other site, but you know, it is my thing why ;-) ). All systems I have seen till today, have every canceled content saved *somewhere* - for at least some time...

Comment: May be - there exist very clever thing: my email address - so is there any problem, why I could not obtain my own text? It is the main thing. Other things I noticed only for you all to have that information by hand for a while, when there will be more similar problems - I thing they will be, but may be they will not happen, time will show ;-)

Comment: @Jii - Deleted questions are only viewable to users with at least 10,000 reputation.

Comment: thank you for answer. I do not need, deleted question to be visible by anybody. I only need, deleted question visible by its author. Not understanding, why in US it is not possible :-o . Here at us it would be ;-)

Comment: @Jii - You will need 10,000 reputation in order to view your deleted questions. That does not change depending on the country in which you reside, and I frankly have no idea where you got the impression that it would.

Comment: @Jii: Unfortunately the feature request for users to be able to see their own deleted questions/answers [has been declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). You can see the reasons why and some discussion of it on that post.

Comment: @David Robinson - very thank for link, it is question what is in my head now.

Comment: @Jack Maney: I do not mean the country of users, but the country of website and the main people, who run it - it was sarcasm.

Answer (score 2):

I feel a little bad for you, because the site can be confusing for new users, especially if English is not your first language. But the other users above are right that your question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange family of sites. It does not really matter that you spent a lot of time on your question or that you are too lazy to write it a second time (your own words). You are still responsible for reading the FAQ and things like that to make sure your posts are okay.

Anyways, this one time, I looked for your question. It is copied below.

> Have you experience of trying different approaches of deploying business web sites?
>
> Are you able to show direction, what type of following to start to learn more deeply? What would you selected if you were on start (with todays experiences)?
>
> - general framework? (zend or something...)
> - CMS like product? (drupal with commerce module or something...)
> - cart product? (opencart or something ...)
> - something else?
>
> Especially when there will be some small (and may be middle) eshop-type websites, what I am goint to build. It is not inside US, so there must be international community (because of easy localization)
>
> Notice: I have programmer experience of different technologies (e.g. some asp, some java, some sql, some others - but it is not important, not watch at it too)
>
> Thank you very much for sharing your experiences with younger collegue ;-)

Original post (MSO 10k-only): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176033/drupal-vs-opencart-vs-zend-framework

Comment: Thank you very much for it. I have it saved on HDD now ;-) For thinking about it 'rightessness' too ;-)