# Why can't I vote to delete this question?

Tags: discussion, voting, vote-to-close, deleted-questions

**This question:** [Does PDO implements mysqli or mysql [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206048/does-pdo-implements-mysqli-or-mysql)

According to the [FAQ on deletion votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222), I should get 25 delete vote for the day (30k rep, 20 extra votes for rep and 5 votes by default). I've only used 4 of them today:

[image]

But the `delete` link isn't even showing up!

[image]

At first I thought it was because I also voted to close it, but I also voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216627/how-to-alphabetize-sentence-in-php), and then voted to delete it, all was fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's @Shog9's fault.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [a very recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/162704):

> The following changes are live now:
>
> - Deleted questions will be visible to their authors, regardless of those authors' reputation. They won't be linked to anywhere that they're not already linked, but if someone knows where to find their question and it's been deleted, they should always be able to view it.
> - Delete-voting within two days of closing is disabled on questions scoring -2 or above, regardless of the voter's reputation.

The second bullet point is the reason you can't vote to delete that particular question, it has a score of 1 and was closed less than two days ago.

Related: [How can we stop premature deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171763/how-can-we-stop-premature-deletion)

Comment: I knew I was missing something. Thanks.