# reopening a question in one site

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions, closed-questions

I have [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10898123/13860). I already revise my question to fit SE criteria. I search the FAQ and it says to reopen a question, other shall initiate the reopening of it. Now I already leave a comment on my question asking to reopening it and no one seems to see it, (no response), and I can't also reopen it by myself. So what is the best remedy here?

PS: my question is located in stackoverflow, and its currently mark as close. already edited it and still no update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've brought it up here, which is good (since this is the place where questions are discussed), but the problem with the question is that you raise that there are 'other factors' but you never talk about those other factors, leaving each answerer to literally guess at what those factors you're thinking of might be.

Your question has a lot of issues with it, I've brought some up and another user [has done so as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134781/16587).  You've also gotten comments on the post that let you know the problems with it (why it's closed).

If you want the question re-opened, you'll need to take the advice listed here and in the comments. Once you do that, it may get more traction for re-open.

In general, and this is not advice on what to do with this question (because of the problems it has), if it's a programming problem that doesn't involve actual code, then you're better off asking it on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Uh oh, here comes the mention of [Programmers.SE] :)

Comment: The question would be closed for exactly the same reason on Programmers. It's simply not a good fit for the Stack Exchange question and answer model.

Comment: ***Never*** suggest something should be migrated to [programmers.se].  You may be right 99% of the time, but that 1% you mess up will haunt you for the rest of your life.  Better safe than sorry.

Comment: [I know you're running for moderator, but...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators)

Comment: [Just missed a vote](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3984257#3984257) ;P

Comment: George, if they didn't love you, they'd just leave you alone :P We forgot to tell candidates that half of the flack they get will be from other moderators.

Comment: @TimPost Hey, I warned the candidates about this, not my fault they don't check the election chat room.

Comment: @ChrisF I wasn't clear in my answer.  I should have said, "all else being equal, if your problem is not about code but about programming (in the specific domain that Programmers is about) then it *may* be better to ask your question there."  Not as a "Yes, please, ask this question on programmers" because it is apparent this question has other problems (which I bring up in my answer)."

Comment: guys, any ideas on how to reopen it? i badly miss stackoverflow :( im hopeless. nobody's reopening it even if i already edited it. link is here ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898123/big-o-notation-for-binary-search

Comment: @Won't See my later comment: I wasn't suggesting it actually be migrated. I wasn't clear in my original post.

Answer (score 4):

From the stackoverflow [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

This means that your question *as is* falls into the "don't ask" group, since there's no actual problem to be solved.

Your question as it stands would lead to a chatty situation where all answers would be an opinion. This defeats the usefulness of the stackoverflow.

**Try to apply a practical example** on the question **with a problem to be solved**, that by getting solved will be given you the answer you seek.

Comment: This reason applies to **all** Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Zuul I love your answer. +1.

Comment: ok tnx zuul, question is how to reopen it