# When flagging a question it should be markable that it belongs to programmers.se

Tags: feature-request, flags, migration

When I flag a question in Stack Overflow as `it doesn't belong here' why can't I choose that it belongs to Programmers.SE?

I have seen some questions which belong more to Programmers.SE than on SO and in my opinion this is a real close site.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As balpha [already mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135235/when-flagging-a-question-it-should-be-markable-that-it-belongs-to-programmers-se#comment376953_135235) the migration path to Programmers was [removed recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators). If you come across questions you think are more suitable for Programmers than Stack Overflow you can:

1. Flag for moderation attention, or
2. Drop the questions in [the Whiteboard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), our main chat room.

It would be extremely nice if you edited the question and fix any obvious spelling / grammar mistakes, removed taglines and signatures, etc, *before* flagging or visiting the Programmers Chat. The question has a lot more chances of getting migrated if it's at the best shape it can possibly be.

Comment: You realize you're damned whatever you choose? Either you have too many options for migration open to normal users, or you have the wrong restricted set (and yes, it'll always be “wrong” since people who think it is right won't be complaining about it).

Comment: @DonalFellows Hm? What's wrong with either option? Both involve the ProgSE community having a say in whether the question fits or not, and that's a good thing, especially when most crap migrations from SO usually were by close voters who didn't even have an account on ProgSE.

Comment: @DonalFellows Wrong is relative, the current options (minus Meta, a standard path) are the most commonly used. There is, currently, no more optimal set to use. In fact even if programmers was used more it wouldn't be an ideal path because of the high rate of rejections.