# What happened to the "Off-topic ... belongs on Programmers" close option?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration, off-topic, software-engineering-se

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update Migration Path List for Non-Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators)

Is my imagination playing tricks on me? I think I remember the list of off-topic "belongs on" options to list programmers.SE. It disappeared. If another "belongs on" entry was more important, why not just add it to the list?

I think there is a significant amount of (great) questions that get asked on SO that belong on programmers.SE, so that should be reflected in the VTC options.

Comment: `I think there is a significant amount of (great) questions that get asked on SO that belong on programmers.SE` Examples? One of the reasons that Programmers was removed from the list is that more than 1 in 3 questions that were migrated there were rejected. And those that made it through, weren't particularly great...

Comment: @eggyal Proposed before and declined.

Comment: @YannisRizos: I only specifically remember a [recent example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10980118/430766). But I recall that there exist several questions where I thought they would be great on programmers.

Comment: That question is off topic for Programmers (although a far better and more specific version of it might be ok), please take some time to read the [Programmers FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: And please stop posting [migration comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980118/c-punctuation#comment14341005_10980118). If you really feel the question belongs on Programmers, follow the [advice here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135235/when-flagging-a-question-it-should-be-markable-that-it-belongs-to-programmers-se/135239#135239).

Comment: @bitmask: "recent example" Thank you for providing the perfect explanation of why the migrate to Prog.SE option was removed. Wes Miller followed your advice and posted it on Prog, where it was [**quickly rejected.**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/152374/28374) You have given a prime example of exactly why this should not be something that SO users can easily do.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Okay, thanks. Learned something. Seems like I constantly misjudge the scope of Programmers.SE.

Comment: It's gone! Thank goodness! Now if we could give the "belongs on Programmers" comments the same insta-burn as the "improve your accept rate" garbage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As shown [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators), Programmers is by far not the most used nor the most successful migration path from Stack Overflow.

We replaced it with TeX, which sees a lot more successful migrations and is going to be a more valuable migration path in the future.

If you see a question that you're sure belongs on Programmers (check the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)!), you can flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated.