# Why is "programmers" not an available option for off-topic flagging?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the “Off-topic … belongs on Programmers” close option?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135489/what-happened-to-the-off-topic-belongs-on-programmers-close-option)

I was flagging [a question regarding work-break-down structures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13432703/254477) on Stack Overflow. IMHO, it is obvious that such managerial topics do not belong on StackOverflow, but they are differently programming related. I wanted to flag it as being "OffTopic", but when the list of related programming sites came up [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) was not available.

It seems from their [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) that it would be an appropriate forum for that type of topic as the say it is for (amongst other things) "development methodologies" and "freelancing and business concerns" under which "work breakdown structures" would be to fall under.

Even if the original question is of too-low quality to be moved, shouldn't moving to Programmers be an option?

Comment: Basic summary: We sucked at migrating stuff over there.

Comment: Also, most of the time, if someone doesn't take the time to read the [faq] and make sure their question is on-topic, then it's probably not good enough to migrate to another site. One rule is don't migrate crap. Migration is reserved for truly exceptional posts.

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago, [we took a look at migration volumes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134636/172958) and Programmers got their wish to be off the quick-migration list.

I just checked the migration stats, and the current list still reflects the top 4 migration targets + meta.