# Why "close as off-topic" does not have an option to migrate to programmers.stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, off-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the “Off-topic … belongs on Programmers” close option?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135489/what-happened-to-the-off-topic-belongs-on-programmers-close-option)

Currently "Close as off-topic" gives us a choice of the following SE sites:

- meta.stackoverflow.com
- superuser.com
- tex.stackexchange.com
- dba.stackexchange.com
- sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Of these, I've used only the SuperUser and DBA options, and I'm positive that I have never, ever used the Tex and SharePoint options.

On the other hand, there are lots of question that are better suited for the Programmers.StackExchange, yet it's not an option.

And since I'm in wishlist mode, could we get a "belongs on" dropdown instead of a fixed list?

Comment: Too much c**p has been migrate to `programmers` that shouldn't have. And lots of people still don't have an idea of what `programmers` accept and do not accept (the FAQ is very restrictive and many things are off-topic).

Comment: You bleeped out crap? Well you're no fun.

Comment: @Oded But I still think that SO -> Prog is still a more common migration path than SO -> Tex.

Comment: @SWeko Common, yes; It was far *too* common.

Comment: @AndyDwyer - Having two little kids does that to a man :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option to migrate to Programmers has been removed because many of the migrations were rejected. (The migrated questions were closed on Programmers after the migration.)

In the list of the sites where a migration is possible, Programmers has been replaced with a site that had enough migrations, and less rejected migrations.

The fixed list is used to avoid confusing users about the site where the question should be migrated; it contains the sites that could possibly be used for a migration.
If there is the need to migrate to other sites, just flag for moderation attention: Moderators are the only users that can migrate question in any site. Just keep in mind the first migration rule: Don't migrate crap.

Answer (score 2):

I think mostly it is because Programmers got tired of all the other sites pooping all over it.

Historically, users from other sites have had very little idea of what kind of subjective questions Programmers encourages, and which kinds it discourages. Not being aware of the distinction, users usually just decide to migrate any subjective question they spot, leaving the Programmers mods the task of sifting through this flood of garbage. To quote [this guy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl):

> To say that Programmers.SE is such a nebulous place and nobody knows
>   what its scope is as the reason why crappy questions keep getting
>   migrated there is to miss the point. Good questions are good questions
>   on all of the sites, and questions that are too vague, that are too
>   argumentative, too localized, and too broad are universal close
>   reasons. There is no special dispensation for Programmers.SE to have
>   bad questions, even if you personally think the questions on there
>   suck.

So now, we have to flag and ask a mod if we think a question should be migrated to Programmers, and I can't say we didn't deserve it.

Comment: Yes, but that is a two years old situation. Is it still valid?

Comment: @SWeko - yes it's still valid. If not more so. Stack Overflow users are **the worst** at deciding where posts should go.

Comment: @SWeko The standards we use for SO are different from the standards they have on Programmers. Unless I've read their FAQ (and why would I, I don't use Programmers) I am not competent to assess whether certain content belongs on their website.