# How to pass a question from stackoverflow to programmers.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the “Off-topic … belongs on Programmers” close option?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135489/what-happened-to-the-off-topic-belongs-on-programmers-close-option)

The most common off topic question I would like to move are the please-review-my-programming-ideas type questions which I assume would be better placed on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).  However, when I try to close as off topic, this is not one of the site it gives me the option to move it to.

Is there something I can do, or should I just close them?

Comment: Flagging like "Isn't this question a better fit for programmers.se?" works for me.

Comment: I used to do that, I would rather something simpler and more constructive for noobs.

Comment: That migration path [was yanked because it wasn't working so well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135489/what-happened-to-the-off-topic-belongs-on-programmers-close-option/135494#135494). We're hesitant to migrate all but the best-written of such questions, even with custom flags telling us to.

Comment: @BradLarson I would accept that as an answer.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl

Comment: could you link a question that fits your idea of please-review-my-programming-ideas I bet they aren't good questions for migration.

Comment: @Ryathal I agree they usually are of the I-have-an-idea-but-I-am-completely-lost variety. Occasionally they have a solid question though, but not for a while.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Programmers used to be a migration target, but far too many Stack Overflow users have no idea what's on topic for us and were voting to migrate any old rubbish which we subsequently had to clear up.

It was (and still is) often users will little or no reputation on Programmers that are suggesting it as a possible destination.

To prevent this the option was taken off the migration dialog.

If you **really** think that a question would be a better fit for Programmers then flag it for moderator attention using the "other" option. If the moderators agree (they have a pretty good idea of the type of question we want) they'll migrate it. But, as Brad says in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163244/how-to-pass-a-question-from-stackoverflow-to-programmers-stackexchange#comment472633_163244) it would have to be a really well written question.

NOTE: This only applies to questions less than 60 days old. Older questions can't be migrated by **anyone**.

In case you are wondering - [I do know what I'm talking about](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/47/chrisf)

Comment: See this [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160929/add-flag-as-other-checkbox-to-vote-to-close-as-off-topic-dialog) to make this all easier.

Comment: @LanceRoberts - we don't want it to be easier. It used to be easier and look what happened.