# Mention general flagging in vote-to-migrate dialog

Tags: feature-request, migration, close-dialog

I [see](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134636/145309) that we've recently changed the list of provided migrations to better reflect the current most popular migration routes. This is good, but it would be really nice if the dialog were to *mention* that general flagging-for-mod-attention should be used to propose a migration to another SE site.

[image: Current vote-to-migrate dialog]

Yes, people using that dialog ought to be aware of that as a possibility anyway through reading Meta, but I'd bet they aren't.

Comment: Note that I don't think that this is a reason to not re-evaluate what migrations should be in the dialog from time to time, and I _do_ agree that only a limited number should be there.

Comment: Why not have a sixth option: flag for migration to _____?

Comment: @Tim Because I didn't think of it. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best thing to do would be to add a button (or replace the final button with one) that says something like:

**It Belongs Somewhere Else:** with a text entry field.

This could act as a standard mod attention flag, but preserves the existing workflow, rather than telling the user to back up and select a different flag type. Bonus points if it would still cast an off-topic close vote for users with appropriate reputation along the way.

Comment: And it needs all the groups.  I just found this question because I googled to figure out how to vote to migrate--and then the board I wanted wasn't on the list.