# What happened to the "migrate to programmers.stackexchange.com" option?

Tags: discussion, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update Migration Path List for Non-Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators)

I'm looking at the question: [Can I provide a GPL app, with different licenced logo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286303/can-i-provide-a-gpl-app-with-different-licenced-logo) which, by my reading is appropriate for Programmers.SE based on the [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) (software licensing).

However, in the "off topic" close options, the following migration options are available:

- meta.stackoverflow.com
- serverfault.com
- superuser.com
- tex.stackexchange.com
- dba.stackexchange.com

What happened to the "programmers.stackexchange.com" migration path?

Comment: They took it away because of users like you :) Just kidding... It ranked 5th in the list of questions migrated (see 10k stats)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators/134642#134642 It happened at the beginning of last month.

Comment: @yoda: What's your opinion of that question? Is that not on topic for programmers.SE? I don't migrate crap.

Comment: @GregHewgill I know, hence the "just kidding" and explanation :) As for an opinion — gee, I don't know; who knows what's on topic at not-really-about-programmers-but-software-engineering-and-whiteboardy-stuff.se?

Comment: oh, you added the "just kidding" part after I first saw your comment.

Comment: @GregHewgill That's right, I was bitten by the enter-submits-comment bug, sorry about that.

Comment: @jonsca: thanks, I hadn't found that question specifically, and seem to have missed this for a month (which indicates how often I actually use the "migrate to programmers" option).

Comment: @GregHewgill I think it slipped under a lot of people's radar, so you're not alone.

Comment: Yannis Rizos won his battle.