# Closing a question pointing to Android.stackexchange

Tags: feature-request, support

There is an increase in some questions on SO, relating to Android, and are not even programming questions [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526585/android-keep-screen-off-against-app-settings/11526813), any chance of putting in android.stackexchange in the list of sites when Off-topic is chosen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> any chance of putting in android.stackexchange in the list of sites when Off-topic

I hope not. The number of posts that should be migrated there, and are on topic over there, are probably far and few to warrant a dedicated item in the list of sites when migrating compared to other sites.

Right now, 18 posts have been migrated from StackOverflow to Android.SE, and 22% were rejected according to the [migration stats](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats).

The current list on StackOverflow is based on the [top 4 migration paths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators), plus Meta which is always the first option.

Comment: Ok cool. TIL! Cheers for your answer! Succinct and sweet! :)

Comment: Yep. The Android tag could do with a bit of a cleanup and better vigilance but there are a lot of tags like that and only so many active users :P