# Would it be possible to get programmer.stackexchange.com in offtopic in review?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow, migration, migration-path-request

Offtopic in review is missing programmers.stackexchange.com which I would choose a lot more often than say tex.stackexchange.com. would it be possible to add/exchange this one?

Comment: It was recently booted off that list due the high number of rejections.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[When we last visited this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators), Programmers wasn't in the top 4 sites migrated to - even though it was already more accessible than some that were. Since then, it's fallen even further:

> Super User × 777 8% rejected
>
> Server Fault × 442 10% rejected
>
> DBA × 346 2% rejected
>
> TeX × 165 9% rejected
>
> Code Review × 131 5% rejected
>
> Meta Stack Overflow × 82 29% rejected
>
> Programmers × 68 8% rejected
>
> SharePoint × 60 1% rejected

(Note that Meta will always be there, regardless of where it falls in the list)

Given the relative lack of demand, I think we'll keep things the way they are for now. If you come across a good question that's off-topic on Stack Overflow but would work on Programmers, just flag for moderator attention and leave a custom message suggesting that it be migrated there.

Comment: 29% rejection from Meta? Seems like we have a problem there... That seems completely outrageous in my eyes. Why are people migrating crap to Meta?

Comment: @animuson A lot of them get closed as dupes - which probably counts as a rejection.

Comment: @Mysticial: Duplicates are the only thing that don't count as a rejection. A rejection means "this question doesn't belong here either." A duplicate question *does* belong here, it's just already been asked before.

Comment: @animuson A rejection means the question was closed (for whatever reason).

Comment: @YannisRizos: The system only "rejects" a question for [non-duplicate and non-belongs-on close reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126982). If the stats still include them, then the stats don't seem all that accurate or useful. I don't consider a question that gets closed as a duplicate to be a bad migration. :/

Comment: @animuson I think that answer only applies to whether the rejection will get locked and the answers that followed it from the source site deleted, that doesn't happen if the question is closed as duplicate. The stats were there long before the rejection mechanism was implemented... "rejected" is just terminology, it does hint to a bad migration, but that's not always the case.