# Is more text needed to educate users on migration to ServerFault?

Tags: discussion, migration, serverfault, migration-rejection

Somewhat related to [Update Migration Path List for Non-Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators) which was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).  In retrospect, it is both a blessing and a curse.  Even though it helped dba.se significantly - we see migrations increased to

- × 318 - 5% rejected from × 144 - 2% rejected

it seems to have quite negatively affected ServerFault

- × 977 **40% rejected** from × 278 - 10% rejected.

The recent drive for **Steward** badges could have a hand in driving up migrations, but the quality of migrations is really low and I suspect must be creating a bit of work for the people on the receiving sites (although only an average of rejecting 4 of 11 a day).

Is there something that can be done about the text within the migration box specifically relating to ServerFault?  Why do so many people get migrations to that site wrong?

Comment: See also Severfault Meta: [Should Server Fault be removed from Stack Overflow's migration list?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3853/19500)

Comment: I did notice a lot of silly off-topic closure votes in the review queue.  It seems like some reviewers think anything that mentions a web server or a database belongs on SF.

Comment: "The server at our local French restaurant was rude and unhelpful. Should I complain to the management?" -  migrate to Server Fault.