# Change suggested sites on the migration list

Tags: discussion, review, off-topic

I have reviewed a rather large number of SO posts, but I'm still very puzzled about the suggested sites on the migration list.

For example, why are [Sharepoint.SE](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) and [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) present but [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) and [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/) are not even when quite a few questions on Stack Overflow are iOS or Android specific.

Recently [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) was replaced by [Sharepoint.SE](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com). How come?

Comment: Regarding sharepoint replacing serverfault, [check this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152596/166025).

Comment: The list isn't based on what sites are likely targets based on the tags you're active in, they're based on the number of migrations made across all of SO, and for that these are the sites most commonly migrated to (with some special casing around serverfault).

Comment: @Servy It is difficult to argue here, but.. I have yet to see a post that should be migrated to TeX.SE :-)

Comment: @TonnyMadsen There's no need to theorize or use anecdotal evidence based on personal experience.  There's a stats page.  (http://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats).  Here are the top 5 over the past 90 days: 1. SuperUser x 1674 2. ServerFault x 760 3. DBA x 332 4. TEX x 135 5. Meta x 89.  The stats don't lie.  Oh, and the TEX rejection rate is 10%, which is fairly low.

Comment: @Servy Thanks.. I'll have a look... :-)

Comment: Or maybe not :-( This page requires 10k rep...

Comment: @TonnyMadsen Yep, that's why I copied the highlighted values for you.

Answer (score 3):

### Why aren't Apple.SE and Android.SE present on the migration list?

Why should they be? The two sites have nothing to do with software development on Android or iOS or Mac OSX. From [Apple.SE's (Ask Different) FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq):

```
Please refrain from asking about ...

   - Apple Developer Programs or iTunes Connect (including iAd and the
     iBookstore)
   - programming, with the exception of AppleScript and Automator
```

And from [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq):

```
Please note the following topics are expressly off-topic here:

    - Developing/programming for Android (please ask these questions on
      Stack Overflow)
```

So basically, these two sites are about the products and hardware, not the development.

### Why are Sharepoint.SE and TeX.SE on the migration list?

Well, they *do* have to do with programming a little bit ([Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) more than [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)). Not really though. The main reason is that because they have to do with programming, new users do ask TeX and Sharepoint questions on Stack Overflow that would probably do better on those sites. We may not have seen them, but I'm sure there were a few... If I'm wrong, please comment.

### And what happened to Server Fault?

[Same thing that happened to Programmers.SE!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators) Too many bad questions were being migrated from Stack Overflow to the site so instead of letting that continue to happen, they removed the site from the list. See here: [Regarding the high number of rejected migrations from Stack Overflow to Server Fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150206/regarding-the-high-number-of-rejected-migrations-from-stack-overflow-to-server-f?lq=1)

TL;DR: Look at [Servy's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160475/change-suggested-sites-for-review-off-topic#comment465449_160475):

> The list isn't based on what sites are likely targets based on the tags you're active in, they're based on the number of migrations made across all of SO, and for that these are the sites most commonly migrated to (with some special casing around serverfault).

Comment: I agree that Android.SE and Apple.SE have nothing to do with programming, but... for the same reason SU.SE is present: there are a lot(!!!) of questions on SO that have to with advance use or administration of these devices. And if the questions are OK, I would like to migrate them to the appropriate sites... Or??