# Sharepoint SE as suggested migration path?

Tags: discussion, support, migration-path-request

Why has Sharepoint SE suddenly popped up in my already limited list of migration paths? The other options aren't great either.

The options I have are:

- Meta SO
- SuperUser
- tex.stackexchange.com
- dba.stackexchange.com
- sharepoint.stackexchange.com

I just considered some of these to be a bit *too* niche and distant from programming in particular, and I'm bewildered that Webmasters and programmers aren't in that list, I mean is LaTeX even anything to do with programming? It's going to take a fairly specific type of question for these paths to be useful.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, some sites have asked to be taken off that list due to the never-ceasing stream of bad migrations.

Answer (score 3):

The list is based, in part, on statistics. If there are a lot of manual migrations to a specific site, it becomes a candidate for automatic migrations.

And it is in part based on how successful automatic migrations have been; loads of bad content being migrated might lead to the target site being removed from the list again.

The list is adjusted based on those two forces on a regular basis.

Remember that you can always flag a post for moderator attention (use the `other` option) to request a manual migration. Mods (on either source or target site) may still decline the migration.

Answer (score 3):

The 4 sites (other than meta) are the 4 top sites in terms of number of successful migrations.  [Martijn's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168911/182513) gives a better overview of how they are actually determined.

Programmers, Webmasters, and Server Fault used to be on this list, and unfortunately SO community members routinely tried to migrate crap because "this is subjective, might be better on Programmers", "this is about IT, it must belong on Server Fault", "This is about running a website, probably better on Webmasters".  In the end these ended up with a lot of rejected migrations, which contributed to removing them from the list of migration paths.

[Update Migration Path List for Non-Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134636/182513) shows the stats and ranking from mid-2012 when Programmers and Webmasters were removed.  Programmers came in 6th and Webmasters can in 10th as you can see.  And in November, [Sharepoint was added in favor of ServerFault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152596/182513).

If you feel there is a really high quality question that was just asked on the wrong site, Mods can still migrate anywhere (as long as the other site agrees).  In that case, you can suggest a migration by flagging with a custom message as to where it should be migrated and why.

Comment: We certainly complained (a lot), but that had nothing to do with Programmers getting off the migration list, we were removed when we dropped sixth in the list of successful migrations (available to 10K+ users). Just complaining about crap migrations isn't enough to get a site of the list.

Comment: @Yannis yeah, I just found the link and noticed that so I've updated my answer

Comment: SU are on the edge of asking to be taken off as well.