# Graying out 'belongs on' options or have them selected on login

Tags: feature-request, migration

I realise that the current five *Belongs on* options in the `off topic` selection is based on [statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168910/sharepoint-se-as-suggested-migration-path/168911#168911) of succesful migrations. And that some others want [more options there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration).

I want less options there or more relevant ones (for me), because on the last two sites mentioned there (dba.stackexchange.com and sharepoint.stackexchange.com) I never logged in and I don't think I ever visited them. I have no clear understanding what the are about apart from the one-liner below the `belongs on` text.
I have a better idea about what questions on tex.stackexchange.com involve, and I visited that but have not felt the need to login, but such visits are probably not so closely tracked as cross-logins.

I suggest that the actual list should be influenced by either the existance of a login for that user for the site.

- Either gray out the ones the user has no login for, or
- give up to five options selected based on the statistics **and** existence of login for that user (and possible reputation on those sites).

Either option should reduce the number of wrong migration proposals, which [seems a problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140376/186664).

Comment: This is a specific feature request, I know the topic of migration has been discussed but have not seen this, so I hope this not going to be a duplicate. If it happens to be a duplicate, I am going to ask for a '10 questions with 100% duplicates' badge. I am sure I will be able to manage that (Bronze is ok).

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to use a *per tag statistic* to determine which sites to show.

So for instance, questions tagged [php](/questions/tagged/php)[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) would probably be migrated to Code Review or Web Masters rather than Sharepoint or TeX.