# How do I get a new question flagged for Migration to Programmers?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration, flag-dialog

According to [this old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators), [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) was removed from the list of migration flag sites.

As a normal user, what is the best way for me to indicate a question probably needs to be migrated to Programmers.SE?

Additionally, it seems redundant to have the list of topics before the list of SE sites to migrate to, especially when both pages suggest [superuser](https://superuser.com/) as a desination. Maybe superuser should be removed from the list of 5 sister sites given that you can flag it as a general hardware/software question on the previous page? It seems silly that the list is limited to the top 5 sites when there are a lot more [technical SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) that questions might need to be migrated to.

For reference, the question in question was this one: [What is a “top-level binding”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436130/what-is-a-top-level-binding)

Comment: Migration didn't go well.  Programmers rejected it as "unclear what you are asking."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Weird that the migration process doesn't throw it to Programmers and then flag it for being unclear. If they don't understand what it means and it doesn't fit in here, why does it both stay here and open? Does it provide feedback to the author at least?

Comment: I cleaned all that up.  Might as well let it live on SO unless and until the community deems it off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention using the Custom option, and put the words "Belongs on Programmers" in the custom description.