# Add programmers.stackexchange.com to off-topic migration site list

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration, software-engineering-se

When voting to close a question that should be migrated to another site, this list of sites is presented:

- meta.stackoverflow.com
- superuser.com
- tex.stackexchange.com
- dba.stackexchange.com
- sharepoint.stackexchange.com

The site **programmers.stackexchange.com** should be added to the list. I don't have hard stats, but it seems like a common migration need.

<sup>FWIW, I encountered this when voting to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19456030/145173).</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, most questions people **think** are suitable for programmers, are **not**. The Programmers moderators have requested to be removed from the migration list precisely because of that.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators

Comment: For some background, see [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382)

Answer (score 6):

Fortunately we *do* have migration stats to work off of:

(migrations from SO over the past 90 days)

1. superuser.com × 222 -  8% rejected
2. dba.stackexchange.com × 158 -  9% rejected
3. tex.stackexchange.com × 115  - 7% rejected
4. meta.stackoverflow.com × 89 -  29% rejected
5. codereview.stackexchange.com × 70 -  2% rejected
6. programmers.stackexchange.com × 41 -  7% rejected
7. webmasters.stackexchange.com × 36  -  5% rejected
8. unix.stackexchange.com × 26
9. wordpress.stackexchange.com × 24  -  4% rejected

Programmers, once upon a time, was a migration target for non-mods.  Because of some unfortunate misunderstandings and radical changes surrounding the site's scope, it ended up being treated as the garbage bin for SO, in which any question SO didn't want they just migrated to programmers to deal with.  Because of the influx of crap, it needed to be removed as a migration target.

While it would be somewhat interesting to know if the mods are seeing a lot of flags requesting migrations to programmers that they are rejecting (See the comments below for some anecdotal comments; thanks mods), at the end of the day with only 41 migrations in 90 days it's not a particularly large number of migrations; that seems entirely within their capabilities to handle.

Comment: I reject all such flags, because I promised Yannis long ago I would *never* migrate things to Programmers. :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Interestingly enough, looking at the migration stats, programmers is now migrating more content to SO than any other site, and it doesn't have a particularly good acceptance rate.  Karma I guess.  SO is now programmer's trash bin.

Comment: @Servy checking my flagging history at Programmers, it happens 2-3 times a week that I catch crappy questions at the risk to migrate to SO due to unfortunate vote split. Moderators handling my flags abort the migration, but a single flagger can only do so much. Crap leaks. Another thing I noticed is questions are rather frequently posted to Prog.SE with the purpose to hop over daily limit at SO through migration and close-voters unfortunately miss this and help abusers

Comment: Last 90 days: SO -> ProgSE 17% rejected - ProgSE -> SO 12% rejected. We still know you guys better than you know us ;)

Comment: @Yannis Those aren't the stats I see from the SO tool.  I see 7% rejected by prog and 18% rejected by SO.  Are you looking on prog's tools?  Why would it be different?

Comment: We do see a significant number of flags asking for migration to Programmers, most of which serve to remind us why it was removed as a migration target.

Comment: @Servy Apparently, the stats have been different for as long anyone remembers, and no one knows why. Interested in posting a bug report? Here's what I see from my end: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VKioj.png

Comment: @Yannis [done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202188/migration-stats-not-consistent-between-sites)