# Concept of "Industry Standard" / "Best Practice"

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration

I understand that principle of asking for "opinion-based" is not welcome on SO, but those questions are very important to development and mastering specific technology field.

Should there be available concept of such questions or do we have a place to migrate them as of now? Close Votes queue is partially based on questions asking for experiences and/or standards (possibly certified) in solving specific problematics.

---

**[Industry Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_standard)** is commonly used solution for given requirements, preferably certified by public standardisation authority such as W3C, IETF, IEEE, also can be solution that was tested on adequate set of test nodes (users, machines, ...) and using appropriate amount of test data  (performance on amount of data, requests, ...).

Comment: Who says such questions are suitable for Programmers? Note that Programmers.SE is not on the migration list on purpose; too many automatic migrations were rejected in the past. You can always flag for *manual* migration by moderator.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry, i concluded from linked question, but we can at least agree that this type of questions is not welcome on SO. And yes, we could mark everything for manual review of moderators, but that is in my opinion unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Related: [Update Migration Path List for Non-Moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134636)

Comment: My point is that most of these kind of questions are not welcome on Programmers **either**. Programmers is not a dumping ground for Stack Overflow 'best practices' questions, do check out the on-topic list there, ask perhaps first ask on their Meta. The moderators at least are better equipped to judge is a question is likely to be closed on Programmers as well.

Comment: The majority of 'best practices' questions in the Close Vote review queue should *not* be migrated, but should be closed instead.

Comment: Yes, but those meant to be migrated should be notified easily for migration to Programmers imo.

Comment: No, they should not. See the 'related' question above; when it was easy a whopping 1 in 4 migrations was rejected. Flagging for moderator attention with an 'other' flag and a short explanation as to why it is suitable for Programmers is easy enough.

Comment: Straight from the [programmers.se] about page: **Don't ask about... Questions that are primarily opinion-based**

Comment: Oh, @Qantas94Heavy great, so the linked question is wrong? If asking about "industry standard solution", is that generally opinion-based? because there is missing such concept.

Comment: @MarekSebera: The answer said used the word **some** of the OP questions might fit on Programmers. I didn't look through the OP question list, so I don't know if I agree there, but the answer certainly did not suggest that *all* such questions belong on Programmers. I think you read too much in the answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't suggest that all such questions should be moved to Programmers either. So this question should be rewritten to match the outcome, hold on.

Comment: @MarekSebera: that then leaves this as a feature request to add Programmers to the list of migration targets, which was asked before and declined. This'd be a dupe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no, we agreed that this shouldn't be added as feature to Programmers, so we need a discussion on how to handle these questions, because "opinion-based" doesn't always mean wrong and "industry standard" can be defined really clearly.

Comment: Please, disambiguate ["Industry standard"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_standard) in terms of programming. Of interest: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598).

Comment: @brasofilo tried to disambiguate the term on bottom of question, also thanks for the related link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand, this principle of asking for "best practice" or "industry standard" is not acceptable for SO.

These type of question aren't acceptable on Programmers either. The [Don't Ask](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page is explicit in the first point on what type of question to avoid.

> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

This is the same on *every* Stack Exchange site - as you can see from the Stack Overflow [Don't Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) page. This is not because the question is a bad question per se, but more because the Stack Exchange model doesn't lend itself to discussion that well. We manage on the meta sites, but that's because the subject matter is Stack Exchange itself and we make allowances.

Our (and I am speaking as a Programmers mod here) [on topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page goes into even more detail about what is on topic and more importantly what is off topic.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a *per se* standard, then asking *what the standard says* about something the standard says something about is not opinion based. If you are asking what is the *de facto* standard by any name including "industry standard", then you are asking an explicitly opinion based question.