# It seems that Programmers should really be on the migration list

Tags: discussion, migration-path-request

Here's a question that needs to be migrated to Programmers, but that site isn't on the migration list:

[What is data type and how is it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357014/what-is-data-type-and-how-is-it-implemented)

I'm aware that the denizens of Programmers were not keen on being on the migration list.  [Update Migration Path List for Non-Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators) .   But this doesn't make sense to me.   I'd be curious to hear the rationale for *not* having Programmers on the list, given that in it's absence all we are going to do is suggest it in a comment...

Comment: if you think a particular question is off-topic on SO _and_ would be a good question on Programmers, flag it for moderator attention (as "other") and ask them to migrate it. (As for whether _non_-moderator migration from SO to Programmers should be allowed, I have no opinion on that.)

Comment: Thx, Done.  I remain curious why we wouldn't put Programmers on the migration list.

Comment: Thx understood.   I think that this comment is actually the answer to my question :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade yeah, realized that 2 seconds to late

Comment: I went and read the guidelines for both sites again, with a critical eye to this question, and I see what you mean.   I have to say it _feels_ more like a Programmers question, but in retrospect, this is likely just because it isn't "u haz da codez".   In respect of SO, it could be said to be about "software tools commonly used by programmers".   Darn, now I have another rejected flag coming my way :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment, Programmers is not on the migration list and probably will not be returning anytime soon.

Programmers **was** on the migration list, but fell off because too many users who did not understand the scope of Programmers tried to migrate crap questions there.  The influx of crap questions from other sites (especially SO due to the volume) can be problem for smaller sites.  It won't get back on until it becomes a more popular and successful migration target and the only way that will happen is if you flag for mod attention and ask them to migrate high quality posts that are off topic on SO.

For your specific question, I agree that Programmers is a best site for that question but that does not automatically make it off-topic for Stack Overflow.  I do think it still fits within the realm of on-topic questions on SO.

There is a lot of overlap between SO and Programmers, and questions that are better on Programmers may still be on-topic  for SO.  It is that overlap that causes another problem for migration.  To be worthy of migration, the question must be off-topic on the site it was asked, but still high quality and on-topic on the target site.

<sup>And just a side note, if you thought the question was off-topic enough to migrate, then answering the question was not the best decision.  Since I think it is on-topic on SO, I don't think answering was the wrong decision.</sup>

Comment: On the side note: why is it wrong to answer a question, assuming it is going to be migrated?

Comment: @GreenAsJade `migration = offtopic` and `offtopic = should not be answerable`.

Comment: My thinking (before being converted by you) was that it was off topic in SO but _on_ topic in Programmers, so I gave the answer that I felt ought to appear in Programmers and flagged it to be moved to Programmers.

Comment: @GreenAsJade fair enough... migration is tricky in general.  I've learned to avoid the feature less I'm absolutely certain it is a good migration.

Comment: It really should be there though. I've seen some excellent questions that are off-topic for SO and should be on Programmers.