# Option to leave a question open from the close link

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

I know this has been asked before and even has a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag on [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close), but I still cannot choose to leave a question open when clicking the "close" link directly under a question, effectively adding an anti-close-vote that weighs in.

Often I see a new question with 1 or 2 close votes on it and I want to vote "leave open", because I think the close vote is not justified. Right now, I have to skip through the massive review queue and hope I find that question.

Am I missing something here? In what way was this implemented as the above mentioned question suggests?

I would really like to see this implemented correctly by adding the option "Leave open" on the dialog that appears when you click "close".

Comment: Yeah, that's a confusing [status-completed]. The "leave open" vote is only available in /review, and that's by design. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673/162704

Comment: @Yannis is correct but as far as I can tell, even the "Leave open" is not undoing the votes just remove the question from the queue. If someone will reach the question directly he will still be able to close it as usual.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Okay, that's my misunderstanding of the process then. I thought they counted as "anti-close-votes" directly. Thanks for that.

Comment: @John nope, even moderator can't do that. More than that - one of the most popular requests on Meta is to [allow a user to undo his own close vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/152859) - which was [declined by Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33949/152859) in one of the most unpopular answers ever. (-176 score)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "even moderator can't do that" Well, that's not _entirely_ true. We can close and immediately re-open, clearing all pending close votes in the process. It's a hack, a side-effect of our binding votes, and not really something we'd use unless it's absolutely necessary.