# Add option to vote for a question to stay open

Tags: feature-request, voting, vote-to-close

Sometimes when going through questions, I can see that someone has previously voted to close it.

[image: Close vote]

However quite often I **disagree** with the close vote and I would like to vote for the question to stay open instead. However I can't do that.

Maybe adding it as an option to this popup:

[image: Close vote 2]

But make it only show up when *not* doing a review task since the review tasks have their own way to vote to keep a question open.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/212780

Comment: @newfurniturey I have been able to vote to reopen since 3k

Comment: @RichardTingle Ah, you're right (sorry, I forgot that 10k gives you ability to see the reopen list - not vote to reopen). As such, 3k is [`Cast Close and Reopen Votes`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

Comment: @GenericHolidayName You're right. I'm flagging as dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voting to keep a question open before it has even been closed is a little pre-emptive. Until a question receives five close votes or a moderator close vote there isn't any guarantee it will actually be closed, and, if a question sits in a state of being open but with close votes on it for a period of time after these votes have been cast, they expire automatically.

Additionally, for the people working the "Close Votes" review queue - there is the option to "Leave Open", which will count as a vote towards keeping the question open. This can only be accessed from within the review queue though. Three "Leave Open" votes in the review queue will take the question out of the Close Votes queue and start ageing the close votes as normal.

Finally, once a question has been closed, it isn't gone. At that point, users with a certain level of reputation as detailed on the privileges page will have the open to cast a reopen vote to reopen the question.

Comment: What is the difference if it is done by a review task or if someone does it manually when they visit the question?

Comment: As Shog9 said: [this is very much by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673/229699).

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently reading that. I don't get *why* it's by design to not be able to do this. Anyway. Just flag this as a duplicate.