# Negative vote to close, prevent question from being closed, instead of only voting to reopen

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I am looking at a valid question with 4 votes to close on a site. I think the collective conscious has edited the question to make it appropriate, and there are answers for that question now.

With one more vote that question will be closed, creating cognitive dissonance about acceptable questions on that site.

The current recourse is to wait for the question to be closed, and then begin voting to reopen.

Instead there should also be a way to negate a vote to close, with a vote to keep open.

Thoughts?

Comment: @Rob maybe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close?

Comment: That'll work too.

Comment: @Rob I see, you sacrificed your close vote to nuke mine :D (I was actually going to retract it because of misreading the question)

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks, I did a cursory search but they all try to describe the same thing in a different way, so current forms of internet searches fail.