# Does Stack Exchange need do-not-close votes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

I've come across different questions at different networks that get closed, the reopened, then closed again...

It's often about questions that represent an edge-case for what's on/off-topic on the corresponding site, or "maybe-opinion-based" questions.

What often happens is that a few people don't think the question is fine and vote to close it while people who think it is can do nothing. Then, when enough "close" votes are reached, the opposite happens (reopen votes until the threshold is met)

I don't know if you think this is fine but for me it's chaotic. A question is either on topic or not, but it can't be on-topic on Tuesday and off-topic by next Friday only to be on-topic again in the weekend. I can think of a few alternatives.

- Closing a question becomes definitive - This appears to me as way too harsh and losing value for the sites (maybe a good edit could save the day).
- Creating a "do-not-close" vote - Questions wouldn't get closed until the "close vs do-not-close count" reaches a certain point (5 more votes for closing, or maybe at least 3 and 66% of total, or any other criterion). Then, questions shall only be reopened by a moderator after an approppriate edit is made.
- Put the "closers" on trial (i.e. make us reputation-responsible for what we decide to flag and close). This means that sound close-requests should be awarded reputation while unsound ones should imply a loss in reputation

**NOTE:** This is my recent experience:

I present you [a closed question with 3 reopen votes](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/142835/looking-for-a-job-in-data-science-should-my-poker-career-be-included) while this post is being made.
[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/142863/is-linkedin-really-useful-for-job-search) will probably be closed and reopened as well.
Meanwhile, [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/24882/novice-capitalizing-on-players-not-knowing-their-openings) has gone through the entire process. I was writing an answer when it suddenly got closed for a few days. Now it's reopened but it's really painful to take the time to rewrite the entire thing

**EDIT**: This question was closed as duplicate, but the linked question is more than 10 years old. A large majority there agreed with the second proposal but nothing has been done since! I would like to understand the reasons why. By the way, if this question gets reopened, it would be the most-meta question ever!

Comment: In the close review queue we do have a leave open vote.

Comment: @rene I have never seen any such queue. I am talking about votes made on the posts themselves

Comment: I've only seen that [queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) ...

Comment: So not playing is an incentive ...

Comment: The example question on Chess is a bit special. That got closed by one mod and got kicked from the re-open queue twice by another mod. Not sure what the do-not-close and reputation/'trial" stuff would have helped there

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog So... It seems everyone wants it. What are we waiting for?

Comment: @David It already exists. We do have a review queue where people can disagree with close votes.

Comment: The question hasn't been closed as a duplicate *yet*; the banner you're seeing is only shown to you since someone *voted* to close as a duplicate. Also, if you read the top answer to that post and its tagging as completed, you'll see that this already exists.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog but leave open votes only exist on review. If you open the close dialog directly on the post you can't vote to leave open. You would have to wait for it to be closed,  before your *disagreement* can be backed with a (re-open) vote. And that is bascially what the OP asks here and that doesn't exist so the dupe doesn't apply if your argument stays as it is. There might be other reasons why it is a good dupe nevertheless but not under your current argument.

Comment: @rene This question doesn't really add any new arguments beyond what is in that question, and it doesn't show any research into how the current system is implemented.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog that is at least a better argument for the dupe, thanks. Lack of research has never been a close reason. That doesn't make the dupe any better

Comment: @David: "*but nothing has been done since! I would like to understand the reasons why.*" [Shog9's answer explains why.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673/164572) You may not agree with his reasoning, but that's still the reasoning. And personally, I find it adequate.

Comment: @NicolBolas Most close-votes do not come from review queues!

Comment: I love how my question receives a gazillion downvotes while the best answer (which is literally repeating what I just proposed) got 10 upvotes. I guess reputation attracts reputation!

Comment: Well, considering your tone, and the fact that your suggestion is *not* an exact match for the answer, it looks pretty reasonable to have such a disparity.  For instance, I see nothing in the answer related to `Put the "closers" on trial (i.e. make us reputation-responsible for what we decide to flag and close)`.  That's just punishing curators for trying to keep the site clean; easiest way to ensure nobody ever does any, and now you're left with a site where you can't find anything, because it's full of junk.

Comment: @David: "*make us reputation-responsible for what we decide to flag and close*" That's fine as long as you're willing to make it work both ways. That is, if you see a question, and you have the rep to close it, but you *don't* vote to close (or vote to leave open), then you will be penalized if it gets closed. Moreso if you answer the question that gets closed. If people can be punished for closing questions incorrectly, then people who *fail* to close questions *correctly* should also be punished.

Comment: @fbueckert Actually, I am not talking only about punishment, but also reward. Anyway, removing reputation from a user is not causing any kind of prejudice, it's just a metric about his activity in the network

Comment: Well, reputation is the level of trust the system has in your ability to contribute to it.  With the gamification aspect, people care a whole lot about imaginary internet points.  The system signalling that your attempt to help clean it up will lose some of those points means less people will do it; it already requires 1 rep to downvote answers, so that happens less often than it should.  Encourage behaviour you want to happen, discourage that which you don't.  I *want* curators to be encouraged to help clean it up, even if they get it wrong sometimes.

Comment: @fbueckert Do you honestly think that what Stack Exchange needs is more downvotes and closed questions? Also "eputation is the level of trust the system has in your ability to contribute to it" that's precisely why I think that, when you make a good contribution (whether it's a question, answer, close-vote...) you should earn reputation; and when you make a bad one, you should lose it.

Comment: `Do you honestly think that what Stack Exchange needs is more downvotes and closed questions?` **Yes**.  Further, punishing people just ensures they don't do *anything*.  Do you fire your janitor the instant he misses a mess?  Seems like a great way to ensure you never have a janitor.

Comment: @fbueckert OK. If that's the premise, I have nothing else to discuss with you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're showing your bias. Why isn't this a request for a "do not re-open" vote?

If there is genuine disagreement, these "just keep it open" or "just keep it closed" solutions always expose that bias… not the actual voting.

"Close wars" are a bit of a misnomer. If there is genuine disagreement, folks have to wait in line to vote the other way in groups of five, back and forth, until you run out of interested parties. **Even if there are 10,000 people wanting to keep it open** and 20 against, you still have to run through four iterations for the flip-flop to end; hence the yo yo effect.

I wrote up a solution eons ago, and it went something like this:

## A Solution to Abate (most) Close Wars

The basic idea to make make sure everyone can vote to "close" or "keep open" so the majority/momentum will quickly drive the decision in one direction or the other **without forcing that whipsaw effect.**

When someone votes to close, change the prompt to read something like this:

> close(+1)? `yes` or `no`
>
> or
>
> `close(+1)` or `keep open`

If someone votes to close, you increment that counter.
If someone votes to keep open, you decrement that counter.

There are ways to make that prompt clearer, but:

If the total vote hit `5`, the post is closed (as it is today).
If the total vote hits `-5`, the prompt goes back to normal.

If there is a true lack of consensus, the vote *may* oscillate between +5 and -5 for a while, but the majority of the time, it is more likely that a general consensus will quickly be reached without forcing the question through that close-reopen-close-reopen cycle.

Of course, if a question is closed (incorrectly), you can reverse that process in the other direction.

> Re-open(+1)? `yes` or `no`
>
> or
>
> `Re-open(+1)` or `keep closed`

A bonus is that the system would no longer have to worry about aging votes (where close-votes eventually expire after a certain period of time). With the +/- votes shown, someone is free to counteract those random close-votes which tend to accumulate over time.

Comment: Would this mechanism also do away with the close and re-open queues? Or would you envision a review queue is still useful to reach the status quo sooner?

Comment: Not sure. The original design of the review queue was to bring attention to situations that might otherwise not be seen, so not entirely sure how this would affect that design specifically.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it creates other problems. Here's the thing: a lot of people (particularly on SO) would vote to keep poor questions open. But they don't have the opportunity to do so, and by the time the last close vote hits such a question, they're not looking at it anymore, because they're sifting through the newer questions. As such, bad questions are properly closed. If these people had the power to *preemptively* stop those who are interested in quality from closing questions, you can basically kiss quality on SO goodbye.

Comment: The only way this would be functional is if "keep open" powers were only granted to 20K rep users; 2K rep is just too easy to scrape together.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think the Stack Exchange community has an obsession with policing "bad" questions. I understand that off-topic questions or plain spam should be closed, of course, but hose cases should be a rare exception, not something like 1 out of every 5 questions

Comment: This reminds me of voting on "tag synonym".

Comment: @David: "*but hose cases should be a rare exception, not something like 1 out of every 5 questions*" I will gladly stop closing bad questions when people *stop asking bad questions*. Changing our standards so that "bad questions" are rare is not the way to make the site better.