# How do I vote against pending delete votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

I’ve opened someone’s existing old closed question and noticed that it has two pending delete votes. I disagree and want to vote against its deletion. How can I do it?

The similar process for [close is implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close).

Comment: Can someone of downvotes explain the reason for downvote? If you agree with PolyGeo answer, my question is still reasonable.

Comment: "Voting is different on meta" https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: You don't seem to be asking for this feature to be implemented, you're asking if it's possible to do this, which makes this a support question, not a feature request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of trying to vote against a question being deleted I think you should edit it to address the reason(s) those delete votes were cast.

Sometimes it’s not obvious why they were cast but in most cases I think it is.

Comment: Sorry, I’ve clarified the question, that  it was not my question, but someone’s else existing question

Comment: Sounds like the quality of the question should be improved

Answer (score 15):

Vote to reopen. If the question is reopened, the delete votes are meaningless since users can vote to delete only on closed questions (and the delete votes get cleared).

So, in a very practical sense, a reopen vote *is* a vote against deletion.

Comment: Well this doesn't work for answers...

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask - If an answer is receiving delete votes then the quality of the answer should be improved

Comment: For the particular question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094688/generate-net-client-from-swagger#comment112518657_54094688 I don’t want to open it as it is off-topic, but it has useful answers and comments, so it shouldn’t be deleted.

Comment: Eh, @michael - read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341987/lets-rescue-wayward-resource-requests-trial-run